# Pivoting Concept

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Hiii,

I have a Database design as:

```
Table File (FileID, Name, Details)

Table Attributes (AttID, AttName, AttType)

Table AttValues (FileID, AttID, AttValue)
```

Till the runtime, it is not known how many `Attributes` are in a `File` and of what names.

And I want to display after insertion at Frontend in a manner like like:

```
FileID, FileName, Details, (Rows of Attribute Table as Column here).
```

i.e., 
Can anybody provide me a piece of code in Java or in MySQL to achieve this Pivoting Result.

Highly thanks full for your precious time.

Or is there any other better way to store data, So that I can get the desired result easily.

Answer (score 1):

This requires two queries. First select the `File`:

```
SELECT * FROM File WHERE (...)
```

Then, fetch the `Attributes`:

```
SELECT *
FROM AttValues
     JOIN Attributes ON (Attributes.AttId = AttValues.AttId)
WHERE FileId = $id
```

The latter query will provide you with one row per `Attribute`, which you can programmatically pivot for display on your frontend:

```
foreach(row in result) {
    table.AddColumn(Header = row['AttName'], Value = row['AttValue']);
}
```

Adapt to your local programming environment as needed.

---

Of course, this only works for a single `File` or `File`s with the same attributes. If you want to display multiple files with different `Attributes` you can instead prefetch all `AttName`s:

```
SELECT Attributes.AttId, Attributes.AttName
FROM Attributes 
     JOIN AttValues ON (Attributes.AttId = AttValues.AttId)
WHERE FileId IN ( $list_of_ids )
```

Then load the values like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM AttValues
WHERE FileId IN ( $list_of_ids )
```

and use a local associative array to map from `AttId`s to column indexes.

As a final optimisation, you can combine the last two queries into an `OUTER JOIN` to avoid the third round trip. While this will probably increase the amount of data transferred, it also makes filling the table easier, if your class library supports named columns.

Comment: Your query gives on row per attribute:

But how to Pivot it Programmaticaly.. I get stucked here.. Neither I could write the PRogam to execute it nor I write a Proicedure to Acheive It..

Help me.. Is there any peice of code to get this..
Thanks 4 ur precious time.

Comment: You're welcome. I've expanded the answer a bit. I hope you can achieve your goals.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question recently: [How to pivot a MySQL entity-attribute-value schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema/652748#652748). The answer is MySQL-specific, but I guess that's OK as the question is tagged with mysql.