# SQL Server: combining multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL query like this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jira.customfieldvalue
WHERE CUSTOMFIELD = 12534
AND ISSUE = 19602
```

And that's the results;

[image]

What I want is; showing in one row (cell) combined all `STRINGVALUE`'s and they are separated with a comma. Like this;

```
SELECT --some process with STRINGVALUE--
FROM Jira.customfieldvalue
WHERE CUSTOMFIELD = 12534
AND ISSUE = 19602

Araç Listesi (C2, K1 vb.Belgeler; yoksa Ruhsat Fotokopileri), Min. 5
araç plakası için İnternet Sorgusu, Son 3 Yıla Ait Onaylı Yıl Sonu
Bilanço + Gelir Tablosu, Son Yıl (Yıl Sonuna ait) Detay Mizanı, İçinde
Bulunduğumuz Yıla ait Ara Dönem Geçici Vergi Beyannamesi, Bayi Yorum
E-Maili, Proforma Fatura
```

How can I do that?

Comment: a.k.a. how to violate 1NF i.e. this is not easy to do in SQL (a smell) by design because it involves generating a non-relational result. Instead do this in a reporting tool, front end code, etc.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There are several methods.

If you want just the consolidated string value returned, this is a good quick and easy approach

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + stringvalue
FROM jira.customfieldValue
WHERE customfield = 12534
    AND ISSUE = 19602

SELECT @combinedString as StringValue
```

Which will return your combined string.

You can also try one of the XML methods e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Issue, Customfield, StringValues
FROM Jira.customfieldvalue v1
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT StringValues + ',' 
              FROM jira.customfieldvalue v2
              WHERE v2.Customfield = v1.Customfield 
                  AND v2.Issue = v1.issue 
              ORDER BY ID 
                  FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( StringValues )
WHERE customfield = 12534
    AND ISSUE = 19602
```

Comment: There is a very good tutorial here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

Comment: If you are going to run this query from PHP, be sure to declare the @combinedstring as fixed length varchar: `DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(255)`

Answer (score 29):

You can achieve this is to combine For XML Path and STUFF as follows:

```
SELECT (STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + StringValue
        FROM Jira.customfieldvalue
        WHERE CUSTOMFIELD = 12534
        AND ISSUE = 19602
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS StringValue
```

Answer (score 19):

This is an old question, but as of the release of Microsoft SQL Server 2017 you can now use the `STRING_AGG()` function which is much like the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in MySQL.

[STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL) Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Example**

```
USE AdventureWorks2016
GO
SELECT STRING_AGG (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),FirstName), ',') AS csv 
FROM Person.Person;
```

Returns

```
Syed,Catherine,Kim,Kim,Kim,Hazem
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a convenient method for this in MySql called GROUP_CONCAT. An equivalent for SQL Server doesn't exist, but you can write your own using the SQLCLR. Luckily [someone](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/) already did that for you.

Your query then turns into this (which btw is a much nicer syntax):

```
SELECT CUSTOMFIELD, ISSUE, dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(STRINGVALUE)
FROM Jira.customfieldvalue
WHERE CUSTOMFIELD = 12534 AND ISSUE = 19602
GROUP BY CUSTOMFIELD, ISSUE
```

But please note that **this method is good for at the most 100 rows within a group**. Beyond that, you'll have major performance problems. SQLCLR aggregates have to serialize any intermediate results and that quickly piles up to quite a lot of work. Keep this in mind!

Interestingly the `FOR XML` doesn't suffer from the same problem but instead uses that horrendous syntax.

Comment: I have a situation where this will only group two or three rows at max, so this is perfect for me in its simplicity. Seeing as this answer is a few years old, has performance of this method improved?

Comment: I know this was posted in 2011, but as of SQL 2017 you can now use the `STRING_AGG()` function, which is like MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` is you want to update your answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe for databases which support ***listagg*** function, you can do:

```
select id, issue, customfield, parentkey, listagg(stingvalue, ',') within group (order by id)
from jira.customfieldvalue
where customfield = 12534 and issue = 19602
group by id, issue, customfield, parentkey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW  [dbo].[ret_vwSalariedForReport]
AS
     WITH temp1 AS (SELECT
     salaried.*,
     operationalUnits.Title as OperationalUnitTitle
FROM
    ret_vwSalaried salaried LEFT JOIN
    prs_operationalUnitFeatures operationalUnitFeatures on salaried.[Guid] = operationalUnitFeatures.[FeatureGuid] LEFT JOIN 
    prs_operationalUnits operationalUnits ON operationalUnits.id = operationalUnitFeatures.OperationalUnitID 
    ), 
temp2 AS (SELECT
    t2.*,
    STUFF ((SELECT ' - ' + t1.OperationalUnitTitle
        FROM
            temp1 t1 
        WHERE t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]  
        For XML PATH('')), 2, 2, '') OperationalUnitTitles from temp1 t2) 
SELECT 
    [Guid],
    ID,
    Title,
    PersonnelNo,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    FullName,
    Active,
    SSN,
    DeathDate,
    SalariedType,
    OperationalUnitTitles
FROM 
    temp2
GROUP BY 
    [Guid],
    ID,
    Title,
    PersonnelNo,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    FullName,
    Active,
    SSN,
    DeathDate,
    SalariedType,
    OperationalUnitTitles
```

Comment: I think use STUFF and FOR XML is the better way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
declare @maxColumnCount int=0;
 declare @Query varchar(max)='';
 declare @DynamicColumnName nvarchar(MAX)='';

-- table type variable that store all values of column row no
 DECLARE @TotalRows TABLE( row_count int)
 INSERT INTO @TotalRows (row_count)
 SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceNo order by InvoiceNo Desc)) as row_no FROM tblExportPartProforma

-- Get the MAX value from @TotalRows table
 set @maxColumnCount= (select max(row_count) from @TotalRows)
 
-- loop to create Dynamic max/case and store it into local variable 
 DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
 WHILE @cnt <= @maxColumnCount
 BEGIN
   set @DynamicColumnName= @DynamicColumnName + ', Max(case when row_no= '+cast(@cnt as varchar)+' then InvoiceType end )as InvoiceType'+cast(@cnt as varchar)+''
      set @DynamicColumnName= @DynamicColumnName + ', Max(case when row_no= '+cast(@cnt as varchar)+' then BankRefno end )as BankRefno'+cast(@cnt as varchar)+''
            set @DynamicColumnName= @DynamicColumnName + ', Max(case when row_no= '+cast(@cnt as varchar)+' then AmountReceived end )as AmountReceived'+cast(@cnt as varchar)+''

      set @DynamicColumnName= @DynamicColumnName + ', Max(case when row_no= '+cast(@cnt as varchar)+' then AmountReceivedDate end )as AmountReceivedDate'+cast(@cnt as varchar)+''


   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

-- Create dynamic CTE and store it into local variable @query 
  set @Query='
     with CTE_tbl as
     (
       SELECT InvoiceNo,InvoiceType,BankRefno,AmountReceived,AmountReceivedDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceNo order by InvoiceNo Desc) as row_no
       FROM tblExportPartProforma
      )
  select
     InvoiceNo
     '+@DynamicColumnName+'
     FROM CTE_tbl
     group By InvoiceNo'

-- Execute the Query
 execute (@Query)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using MySQL inbuilt function **group_concat()** will be a good choice for getting the desired result. The syntax will be -

```
SELECT group_concat(STRINGVALUE) 
FROM Jira.customfieldvalue
WHERE CUSTOMFIELD = 12534
AND ISSUE = 19602
```

Before you execute the above command make sure you increase the size of **group_concat_max_len** else the the whole output may not fit in that cell.

To set the value of group_concat_max_len, execute the below command-

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 50000;
```

You can change the value 50000 accordingly, you increase it to a higher value as required.

Comment: Thanks but sorry, my question was for "T-SQL" as you can see. Your answer was _also_ included in [Combine Multiple child rows into one row MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1067428/447156) by the way.