# Merging multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

View **MyView**:

```
............. 
. Id | Value.
.............
.  1  |  A  .
.  2  |  B  .
.  3  |  C  .
.  4  |  D  .
.............
```

My query as following:

***"Select From dbo.MyView Where Id > 1"***

Real results:

```
.............
. Id | Value.
.............
.  2  |  B  .
.  3  |  C  .
.  4  |  D  .
.............
```

---

My wished or desired result:

***"B, C, D"***

---

I need one string(one row, one column) which merege all values of the column Values.

How can I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Scalar Valued Function:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetResults] 
(
    @ID int
)
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(200)

    SELECT @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ', ','') + Value
    From
        (   
            SELECT  Value
            FROM       MyTable
            WHERE     (ID > @ID)

        ) UniqueValues

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it seem to be exactly what we need! how can we called from a nested query? can we do that for example (SELECT .... SELECT(. HERE CALL IT..))

Comment: just use `select... select(...., dbo.GetResults(ParameterHere) as Results, ....)`

Comment: The answer is correct but it not working for Views we have a view and not a table.

Comment: This works fine for me when using a view: CREATE VIEW [MyTestView] AS SELECT [dbo].[GetResults](1) AS [ValueString];
SELECT * FROM [MyTestView]; User3805967, you may be implementing this wrong, can you post more code?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

`SELECT ','+Value from MyTable for xml path('')`

OR

```
declare @test varchar(100)
select @test = coalesce(@test+',','')+Value from MyTable
select @test
```

Comment: dear It must done in the SQL-Server not in code the query must be modified thanks for help.

Comment: Didn't get you. You dont want to achieve it using sql?

Comment: no I want do do it with SQL something like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Comment: Your answer is also correct thanks but but it not working for Views we have a view and not a table. Scalar not working :(

Answer (score 1):

For a View use the solution proposed by Milen, create the Scalar Valued Function, and then in the View just use "dbo.GetResults(ParameterHere) as Results"

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what we need +1 for you but I will marke the milen Answer!