# get result of 2 rows value in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, string-aggregation

result of a join query-

```
SELECT st_stock.name, st_stock.price, 
       FORMAT(st_stock.quantity,0), 
       st_stock.exp_date, 
       admin.username 
FROM `st_stock` 
  INNER JOIN `admin` ON FIND_IN_SET(admin.ID,st_stock.broker_id) AND st_stock.id='2'
```

Sample Data

```
name        price     asjdb       exp_date            username
5.HK (HSBC) 74.40 HKD 100,000,000 2018-07-27 17:00:00 broker2
5.HK (HSBC) 74.40 HKD 100,000,000 2018-07-27 17:00:00 broker3
```

Expected Output

```
 5.HK (HSBC) 74.40 HKD 100,000,000 2018-07-27 17:00:00 broker2,broker3
```

Comment: my result should be--- 5.HK (HSBC) 74.40 HKD 100,000,000 2018-07-27 17:00:00 broker2,broker3

Comment: [edit] your question. Do not add additional information as (unformatted) comments

Comment: Do you have column names for your expected output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate row values T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql)

Comment: same column name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Comment: Please add your comment with an expectation into a question and format it properly.

Comment: actually that result which i showed you, that get from a join query- "SELECT  st_stock.name, st_stock.price, FORMAT(st_stock.quantity,0), st_stock.exp_date,admin.username FROM `st_stock` INNER JOIN `admin` ON FIND_IN_SET(admin.ID,st_stock.broker_id) AND st_stock.id='2'"

Comment: Despite the unclearence I believe that the best way is to look at the `PIVOT` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is sql,

```
 SELECT st_stock.name, st_stock.price, 
           FORMAT(st_stock.quantity,0), 
           st_stock.exp_date, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(admin.username)
    FROM `st_stock` 
      INNER JOIN `admin` ON FIND_IN_SET(admin.ID,st_stock.broker_id) AND st_stock.id='2' GROUP BY st_stock.name
```

Comment: @SmritimayDebnath its workign fine,right? Make sure you to click up arrow to vote good ans :D

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the SQL engine you are using.  When it comes to more advanced aggregate and windowing functions, implementations vary across database engines.

In PostgreSQL for example, you would use the [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function:

```
SELECT name, price, asjdb, exp_date, string_agg(username,',') AS username
FROM d
GROUP BY name, price, asjdb, exp_date;
```

For other database engines you would use:

1. Oracle: [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)
2. SQL Server: [STRINGAGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
3. MySQL: [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

**Further Reading:**
[ListAGG in SQLSERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver)

Comment: Thanks for the engine tag!