# SQL Server: Combine multiple rows into one row from a join table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have an SQL query that looks like this.

```
SELECT ID, Data1, DataFromTable2
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE ID = 1
```

I'm trying to join the two tables where Table2 (which contains multiple rows with the same ID). And I want to  the multiple rows into one row.

I found a post here that combines the multiple rows into one.
[SQL Server: combining multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + stringvalue
FROM jira.customfieldValue
WHERE customfield = 12534
AND ISSUE = 19602

SELECT @combinedString as StringValue
```

But I'm having a hard time applying it to the above query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server. my bad, forgot to mention in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` query with `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Data1,
    STRING_AGG(t2.DataFromTable2, ',') AS data
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.Data1
WHERE
    t1.ID = 1;
```

I am assuming you are using SQL Server 2017 or later.  For earlier versions of SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Data1,
    data = STUFF((
      SELECT ',' + t2.DataFromTable2
      FROM Table2 t2
      WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table1 t1;
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2017 and 2018 but I'm getting an error
       Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 566
       'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Then maybe your version does not support it.

Comment: i see. 
are there other ways to do it aside from your answer?

Comment: @bigbryan Yes, you may use `STUFF`, but you need a big ugly query in this case.  Strange that `STRING_AGG` does not work for you.

Comment: @bigbryan . . . Check your compatibility level:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15.