# How to merge multiple row in a single rows in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here is my sample table.(Sql)

```
City UserId UserName Campagin
Mumbai 1    Smita    TeachIndia
Mumbai 1    Smita    SaveTree
Mumbai 1    Smita    CleanCity
Pune   2    Rashmi   GreenCity
Pune   2    Rashmi    SaveTree
```

I want output like this

```
City UserId UserName Campagin
Mumbai 1    Smita    TeachIndia,SaveTree,CleanCity
Pune   2    Rashmi   GreenCity,SaveTree
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: which database?

Comment: tag your question with proper dbms

Answer (score 0):

If it's SQL Server, then you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    city, userid, username, 
    campaign = STUFF((SELECT ',' + campaign 
                      FROM tbl t1
                      WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    tbl t2
GROUP BY
    city, userid, username
```

Comment: I have added city also in where clause.Then it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below links for multiple possible solutions over this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

[SQL Server: combining multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row)