# Price data from different days into one row/two columns

Tags: sql

I have a list of order and a list of historical prices, so let's say

Transactions:

| Transaction_no | ID_no | Price_Traded | Trade_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | a | 10.9 | 20210720 |
| T2 | b | 58.7 | 20210720 |

Prices:

| ID_no | Price_Theo | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10.5 | 20210718 |
| a | 10 | 20210719 |
| a | 11 | 20210720 |
| b | 62 | 20210718 |
| b | 59 | 20210719 |
| b | 58 | 20210720 |

I want to obtain a list where I can compare the traded price with the theoretical price from that day and from the day before. So ideally a list like this:

| Transaction_no | ID_no | Price_Traded | Trade_Date | Price_Theo_TD | Price_Theo TD-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | a | 10.9 | 20210720 | 11 | 10 |
| T2 | b | 58.7 | 20210720 | 58 | 59 |

Is that possible? Right now I am only able to get a list like:

| Transaction_no | ID_no | Price_Traded | Date | Price_Theo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | a | 10.9 | 20210719 | 10 |
| T1 | a | 10.9 | 20210720 | 11 |
| T2 | b | 58.7 | 20210719 | 59 |
| T2 | b | 58.7 | 20210720 | 58 |

The code used here should look like this:

```
SELECT T.Transaction_no, P.ID_no, T.Price_Traded, P.Date, P.Price_Theo
FROM Transactions T 
    right join Prices P on T.ID_no = P.ID_no
WHERE T.Transaction_no in ('T1', 'T2')
    AND P.Date in (T.Trade_Date, T.Trade_Date - INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

Note: I do know the discussion from [SQL Server: combining multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row) and other boards. But my questions differs, since I want information from the second row into an additional column. I do not want to concatenate stuff in one variable.

Note2: I thought about PIVOT - but this only works with aggregating functions and I do not want to aggregate anything.

Thanks a lot! Would be happy for any help. Also if there is an existing discussion on that topic.

Cheers

KidLu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two joins:

```
SELECT T.Transaction_no, P.ID_no, T.Price_Traded,
       P.Date, P.Price_Theo,
       P1.Date, P1.Price_Theo
FROM Transactions T LEFT JOIN
     Prices P 
     ON P.ID_no = T.ID_no AND
        P.Date = T.Trade_Date LEFT JOIN
     Prices P1
     ON P1.ID_no = T.ID_no AND
        P1.Date = T.Trade_Date - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```