# How can I combine rows in SQL with separate columns containing repeated values?

Tags: sql

my task is to combine several rows into one column, only the rule is that some of the things that are repeated should stay. Task is to the student table. I will give an example:

```
Student_ID | Sex | Field_Of_Study | Department | Term | Subject | Grade_1 | Grade_2 | Grade_3|
-----------|-----|----------------|------------|------|---------|---------|---------|--------|
      1       M        Comp_scie      Inf        3       Electr      2         3        0
      1       M        Comp_scie      Inf        3       Python      4         0        0
      1       M        Comp_scie      Inf        3       Java        3         4        0
```

And my task is to make it looks like that:

```
Student_ID | Sex | Field_Of_Study | Department | Term | Subject_1 | Grade_11 | Grade_12 | Grade_13| Subject_2 | Grade_21 | Grade_22 | Grade_23| Subject_3 | Grade_31 | Grade_32 | Grade_33|
-----------|-----|----------------|------------|------|-----------|----------|----------|---------|-----------|----------|----------|---------|-----------|----------|----------|---------|
      1       M        Comp_scie      Inf        3       Electr        2           3        0        Python        4         0            0         SQL         2         3        0
```

Is there any option to make it looks like this using SQL ?

I tried to create a script that will arrange this table, but I have too little skills to connect it in this way or at least similar.

Comment: I'd assume this being vendor specific; at least for MS SQL you might want to peek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005846/sql-server-combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Student_Id isn't unique so make it either unique or assign a primary key to it so it'll accept only single value.

Hope this will help you achieving the desired output.

Thanks & Regards. For any requirements or more information about the given solution cmnt down, I'll share it.