# how to make a tables rows into columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table called "attributes" which i need to be columns in our query. These columns need to then join our "products" table and be populated with the data from "productattributevalues".

Table: Attributes

Fields:

- id
- name

Table: Products

Fields

- id
- name
- description
- other fields which contain more information about the product

Table: ProductAttributeValues

Fields:

- id
- attribute id
- product id
- value

How can I get the rows from attributes to be columns alongside the products and have them populated with the values from productattribute values and have unique results.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many attributes you have you can join against the attribute table multiple times. If you don't know how many you could use GROUP_CONCAT.
Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql) for GROUP_CONCAT .

You could also use a second query to get them, which is a practical choice for many use cases.