# How to make mysql answer in only one line

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Results as comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)
>   [Combine Multiple child rows into one row MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql)
>   [SQL query to pivot a column using CASE WHEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when)

[image]

I want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT `name` AS `data` FROM `test_table` WHERE `level` = 1 ORDER BY `id`;
```

But I want it to answer me in only one line with a '`,`' ! Like this:

```
data = a,b,
```

Without using PHP, is it possible using only MySQL? How? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ';')
FROM    test_table
WHERE   level = 1
```

Comment: Woow great! thank you so much ! Can I make GROUP_CONTAT add something different than "," ?

Comment: Thank's!  But `ORDER BY `id``  Won't work if I put SEPARATOR.