# Combine multiple rows into one MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need some help. I googled for solution, but I didn't found one.

I have three tables:

```
langs
(int) id | (varchar) language
    1    |       English
    2    |        Latin
    3    |      Esperanto
   ...   |         ...

keys
(int) id | (varchar) keys
    1    |       dog
    2    |       cat
   ...   |       ...

value
(int) id | (int) key_id | (int) lang_id | (varchar) value
    1    |       1      |        1      |        Dog
    2    |       1      |        2      |       Canis
    3    |       2      |        1      |        Cat
    4    |       2      |        2      |       Felis
    5    |       2      |        3      |        Kato
   ...   |      ...     |       ...     |        ...
```

and I want to get the result:

```
key_id |  keys  |  English  |  Latin  |  Esperanto  
   1   |  dog   |    Dog    |  Canis  |    NULL
   2   |  cat   |    Cat    |  Felis  |    Kato
  ...  |  ...   |    ...    |   ...   |    ...
```

merging rows with equal `key_id`. I know I can try to make it with multiple JOINs, but it's slow and I must know the exact number of different `langs`.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine Multiple child rows into one row MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  ' SELECT `value`.`key_id`,'
,        '`keys`.`keys`,'
,         GROUP_CONCAT(
           'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`value`.`lang_id`=',id,',`value`.`value`,NULL))'
          ,   ' AS `', REPLACE(language, '`', '``'), '`'
          )
, ' FROM `keys` JOIN `value` ON `value`.`key_id` = `keys`.`id`'
, ' GROUP BY `value`.`key_id`'
)
INTO @sql
FROM `langs`;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need but there is a problem. When I reproduce it on my localhost DB via phpMyAdmin, I get error `#1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE`. The code is working when I select the `@sql` variable and run it. I tried with other prepared statements, they are working too. I googled for similar problems, but couldn't find solution.

Comment: @erik1001: Are you using the same statement handler in your `PREPARE` statement?

Comment: Of course it has the same name, but anyway I have to do it with separate queries, one to build the stmt and one do execute it, because CI does not allow multiple queries, so everything is OK. Thank you very much, you have my upvotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking at a pivot table. It Is doable, though the code is a bit cumbersome.

one source: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

In the end though most any mysql solution will require either some wizardry with stored procedures or... hardcoding what languages you return.

Pivot tables are one area that mysql doesn't shine in.