# How merge multiple rows into one row?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine Multiple child rows into one row MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql)

I have following table,

```
count     | inventory_id | resource_id | id
---------+-----------+----------------------
10        | 1            | 1           | 1
20        | 2            | 1           | 2
30        | 1            | 2           | 3
40        | 2            | 2           | 4
```

I want to merge rows where resource_id is equal and also want to give alias for each count according to inventory_id. I need to give alias "Resource 1" for count where inventory_id =1 and "Resource 2" where inventory_id=2

output needed:

```
Resource 1| Resource 2    |resource_id 
---------+-----------+-----------------
10        | 20            | 1             
30        | 40            | 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN inventory_id = 1 THEN `count` END) AS 'Resource 1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN inventory_id = 2 THEN `count` END) AS 'Resource 2',
  resource_id
FROM table 
GROUP BY resource_id
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/571dc/3)

This should give you:

```
RESOURCE 1  RESOURCE 2  RESOURCE_ID
10             20                1
30             40                2
```

Comment: Thanx Mahmoud...My problem resolved

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT
  resource_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN inventory_id = 1 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS 'Resource 1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN inventory_id = 2 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS 'Resource 2'
FROM table1
GROUP BY resource_id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4aba/5)

but if you have unknown value of `inventory_id` not just (`1 and 2`), better use `PreparedStatement`

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN inventory_id = ',
      inventory_id,
      ' THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS ''RESOURCE ',
      inventory_id, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT resource_id, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM table1 
                   GROUP BY resource_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4aba/24)

Comment: [Another Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4134/1)