# How to make sql query returns only in 1 row? or How to merge or combine the 2 results into 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, laravel-4

**Question:**

- How to make merge or combine the 2 team results into 1? Or
- How to make it returns only in 1 row?

**Table name:** *series_type*

```
id| type| description 
1 |    0| No series (Any team win 1 will be the winner)
2 |    1| Best of 3 (Any team wins 2 will be the winner else draw)
3 |    2| Best of 5 (Any team wins 3 will be the winner else draw)
```

**Table name:** *teams*

```
       ID| name 
  1848158| LV
       15| LGD
```

**Table name:** *matches*

```
ID| series_id | series_type | league_id | start_time |radiant_name | dire_name | radiant_win
1 |      8313 |           2 |      2096 |   xxxxxxx1 |          LV |       LGD | true 
2 |      8313 |           2 |      2096 |   xxxxxxx2 |         LGD |        LV | false
3 |      8313 |           2 |      2096 |   xxxxxxx3 |          LV |       LGD | false
4 |      8313 |           2 |      2096 |   xxxxxxx4 |          LV |       LGD | false
5 |      8313 |           2 |      2096 |   xxxxxxx5 |         LGD |        LV | false
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT series_id, team, SUM(Win) As Won, SUM(Loss) as Lost
FROM
( SELECT *,radiant_name as team, 
     CASE WHEN radiant_win = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
     CASE WHEN radiant_win = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Loss
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *,dire_name as team, 
     CASE WHEN radiant_win = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
     CASE WHEN radiant_win = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Loss
  FROM matches
) as temp
WHERE series_id = 8313
GROUP By team
ORDER By Won, Lost DESC
```

**Results:** *when group by series_id*

```
series_id| team| Won| Lost|
     8313|   LV|   5|    5|
```

**Results:** *when group by team*

```
series_id| team| Won| Lost|
     8313|  LGD|   2|    3|
     8313|   LV|   3|    2|
```

**Expected Results:** *i need it group by series_id*

```
series_id| teamA| teamB| teamAWon| teamBWon| teamALost| teamBLost|
     8313|    LV|   LGD|        3|        2|         2|         3|
```

Comment: I answered, but can you please post your table structure, and a clear statement of the result you want? Also, are there more than two teams in the series? Or are the same two teams playing every match in a series?

Comment: Why include the original table and structure?

Comment: please review it again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main complicating factor is that each team name can appear in radiant_name or dire_name 0 or more times. So it's a little complicated to pivot the teams into one column per team name. It would be easier if matches had a constant teamA and teamB column, and then a column to indicate which team was radiant and another column to indicate which team won.

This is almost certainly not optimal, but it appears to work:

```
-- create a two-column temp table with series ID and team name, insert rows from matches
-- we'll wind up with one row per distinct radiant_name and distinct dire_name,
-- so up to 4 rows for a series
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempteama AS
select distinct series_id, radiant_name AS team
from matches
union
select distinct series_id, dire_name AS team
from matches;

-- do this again in a second temp table, so we can join the two later
-- (MySQL doesn't like to join temp tables against themselves)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempteamb AS
select distinct series_id, radiant_name AS team
from matches
union
select distinct series_id, dire_name AS team
from matches;

-- join matches against the temp table to get final results
select matches.series_id, 
teamA, 
teamB, 
sum(case when (radiant_name = teamA AND radiant_win=1) OR (dire_name=teamA AND radiant_win=0) then 1 else 0 end) AS teamA_win,
sum(case when (radiant_name = teamB AND radiant_win=1) OR (dire_name=teamB AND radiant_win=0) then 1 else 0 end) AS teamB_win
from matches
join (
-- select just one row from the temp table. That gives us the combination of teams for the series.
select tempteama.series_id, tempteama.team AS teamA, tempteamb.team AS teamB
from tempteama
join tempteamb on tempteama.series_id = tempteamb.series_id and tempteama.team != tempteamb.team
limit 1
) AS teamnames on teamnames.series_id = matches.series_id
group by matches.series_id, teamA, teamB;
```

You could probably do the temp table queries as sub-queries, at the expense of some readability.

Comment: hey can you take a look a this. this is the main . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054402/how-to-query-counting-specific-wins-of-team-and-find-the-winner-of-the-series

Comment: OK...for a particular series, will a given team be the radiant team and the dire team at least once? Or is it possible that the same team will be the radiant team for all matches in the series?

Comment: the match will be given each team random position as radiant or dire. so no only 1 team for dire and 1 for radiant.

Comment: why it returns zero results?

Comment: For me it returns one row:'8313','LGD','LV','2','3'
Maybe the table I created has a different structure than your matches table. What's your column type for `radiant_win`?

Comment: dont know what to do T_T im stuck to this query

Comment: radiant_win column type is tiny int

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to enter messages. maybe you should sleep now. then maybe can you help me after you wake up. btw thanks. i will be waitingyou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65431/discussion-between-jscott-and-ronscript).

Answer (score 0):

I have two results for this question one is for any sql and other for oracle sql(as i used oracle function in it)

One can run this solution on any sql:-

```
SELECT AB.SERIES_ID,TEAMA,TEAMB ,TEAMAWON,COUNT(STC.SERIES_ID)-TEAMAWON TEAMBWON,
COUNT(STC.SERIES_ID)-TEAMAWON TEAMALOST,
COUNT(STC.SERIES_ID)-(COUNT(STC.SERIES_ID)-TEAMAWON) TEAMBLOST FROM  
(
  SELECT MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME TEAMA,MA.DIRE_NAME TEAMB ,
  COUNT(RADIANT_WIN) TEAMAWON FROM MATCHES MA,SERIES_TYPE ST
  WHERE  MA.SERIES_TYPE=ST.TYPE   
  GROUP BY MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME
) AB, MATCHES STC 
WHERE (AB.SERIES_ID,AB.TEAMAWON) IN
  (
    SELECT SERIES_ID,MAX(RADIANT_WIN) RAD
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME ,COUNT(RADIANT_WIN) RADIANT_WIN 
        FROM  MATCHES MA,SERIES_TYPE ST
        WHERE  MA.SERIES_TYPE=ST.TYPE   
        GROUP BY MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME
    )
     GROUP BY SERIES_ID
 ) AND STC.SERIES_ID=AB.SERIES_ID AND  TEAMA IN (RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME)
 GROUP BY AB.SERIES_ID,TEAMA,TEAMB ,TEAMAWON;
```

Now i m writing the Solution for the oracle people who are seeking for the same result using oracle :-

```
SELECT SERIES_ID,GREATEST(RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME) TEAMA,
LEAST(RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME) TEAMB ,max(RADIANT_WIN) TEAMAWON,
SUM(RADIANT_WIN)-max(RADIANT_WIN) TEAMBWON,
SUM(RADIANT_WIN)-max(RADIANT_WIN) TEAMALOST,
SUM(RADIANT_WIN)-(SUM(RADIANT_WIN)-Max(RADIANT_WIN)) TEAMBLOST
FROM
(
   SELECT MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME ,
   COUNT(RADIANT_WIN) RADIANT_WIN FROM MATCHES MA,SERIES_TYPE ST
   WHERE  MA.SERIES_TYPE=ST.TYPE 
   GROUP BY MA.SERIES_ID,MA.RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME
) GROUP BY SERIES_ID,
  greatest(RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME) ,least(RADIANT_NAME,DIRE_NAME);
```

Comment: too many error. can you make for mysql version im using phpmyadmin. thanks

Comment: ookk so you are running it on mysql environment .. may be it may not work as i did it on oracle and sql dbms .I am trying to find any online phpmyadmin environment  to work and will be back soon with query on this dbms

Comment: thanks a lot for time. hope you make it. because i really really need it to become optimize also.

Comment: please take a look. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/combine-column-from-multiple-rows-into-single-row this is the same result i want..