# How to optimize query when using sub-queries in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

**Tables:**
*Please take a look here to see tables. [How to query counting specific wins of team and find the winner of the series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054402/how-to-query-counting-specific-wins-of-team-and-find-the-winner-of-the-series)*

**Questions:**

- How to make query more optimize?
- How to reduce query redundancy?
- How to make this query more faster?

**Summary**

*As you can see in the example query this part is use many times.*

```
WHERE leagueid = 2096
AND start_time >= 1415938900
AND ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 AND matches.dire_team_id= 15)
OR (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 AND matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

---

```
SELECT matches.radiant_team_id,
       matches.dire_team_id,
       matches.radiant_name,
       matches.dire_name,
       TA.Count AS teamA,
       TB.Count AS teamB,
       TA.Count + TB.Count AS total_matches,
       SUM(TA.wins),
       SUM(TB.wins),
       (CASE
            WHEN series_type = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN series_type = 1 THEN 2
            WHEN series_type = 2 THEN 3
        END) AS wins_goal
FROM matches
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT radiant_team_id,
          COUNT(id) AS COUNT,
          CASE
              WHEN matches.radiant_team_id = radiant_team_id && radiant_win = 1 THEN 1
          END AS wins
   FROM matches
   WHERE leagueid = 2096
     AND start_time >= 1415938900
     AND ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158
           AND matches.dire_team_id= 15)
          OR (matches.radiant_team_id= 15
              AND matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
   GROUP BY radiant_team_id) AS TA ON TA.radiant_team_id = matches.radiant_team_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT dire_team_id,
          COUNT(id) AS COUNT,
          CASE
              WHEN matches.dire_team_id = dire_team_id && radiant_win = 0 THEN 1
          END AS wins
   FROM matches
   WHERE leagueid = 2096
     AND start_time >= 1415938900
     AND ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158
           AND matches.dire_team_id= 15)
          OR (matches.radiant_team_id= 15
              AND matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
   GROUP BY dire_team_id) AS TB ON TB.dire_team_id = matches.dire_team_id
WHERE leagueid = 2096
  AND start_time >= 1415938900
  AND ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158
        AND matches.dire_team_id= 15)
       OR (matches.radiant_team_id= 15
           AND matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
GROUP BY series_id
```

**Scheduled Matches**

```
ID| leagueid| team_a_id| team_b_id| starttime
 1|     2096|   1848158|        15| 1415938900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done without subqueries.

I made the following match table

[image]

And used the following query to group results, one line per series

```
SELECT 
      matches.leagueid,
      matches.series_id,
      matches.series_type,
      COUNT(id) as matches,
      IF(radiant_team_id=1848158,radiant_name, dire_name) AS teamA,
      IF(radiant_team_id=1848158,dire_name, radiant_name) AS teamB,
      SUM(CASE
           WHEN radiant_team_id=1848158 AND radiant_win=1  THEN 1
           WHEN dire_team_id=1848158 AND radiant_win=0 THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END) AS teamAwin,
      SUM(CASE
           WHEN radiant_team_id=15 AND radiant_win=1  THEN 1
           WHEN dire_team_id=15 AND radiant_win=0 THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END) AS teamBwin

FROM `matches` 
WHERE leagueid = 2096
     AND start_time >= 1415938900
AND dire_team_id IN (15, 1848158)
AND radiant_team_id IN  (15, 1848158)
group by leagueid,series_id,series_type,teamA,teamB
```

which yields the following result

[image]

Please note that, when grouping the results of one series, there isn't such thing as radiant team or dire team. The radiant and dire roles might be switched several times during the same series, so I only addressed the teams as teamA and teamB.

Now, looking at your prior question, I see that you need to determine the series winner based on the series type and each team victories. This would need to wrap the former query and use it as a subquery such as

```
SELECT matchresults.*,
      CASE series_type
      WHEN 0 then IF(teamAwin>=1, teamA,teamB)
      WHEN 1 then IF(teamAwin>=2, teamA,teamB)
      ELSE IF(teamAwin>=3, teamA,teamB)
      END as winner

from ( THE_MAIN_QUERY) as matchresults
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOH . THATS IT. YOUR THE BEST. THANK YOU VERY MUCH . THIS PROBLEM IS 1 week OLD ~_~/ AND THEN AT LAST . YOU SOLVED IT :D THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: i have question. what if i want to make radiant_team_id and dire_team_id dynamic? example i dont want to filter out using team id.

Comment: It depends. A series identifies a unique team pair? Or it does address a stage that can apply to several team pairs? Beyond that, you need to consider how much logic will lie at the model level and how much can be managed with business logic.

Comment: btw. Thanks. my problem now is how can i cinvert this to laravel queries. :D

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't ever used eloquent ORM, but it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: hi i updated below table. how do i join scheduled matches here. please see above updates

Comment: I encourage you to create a new question, linking the prior related questions to provide context.

Comment: hi . here please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108029/how-to-left-join-on-multiple-columns-using-my-query

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient ways to get the results you want.  But, to make this query  more efficient, you can add indexes.  This is the repeated `where` clause:

```
WHERE leagueid = 2096 AND
      start_time >= 1415938900 AND
      ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 AND matches.dire_team_id= 15) OR
       (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 AND matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

Conditions with `or` are hard for the optimizer.  The following index will be helpful:  `matches(leagueid, start_time)`.  A covering index (for the `where` conditions at least) is `matches(leagueid, start_time, radiant_team_id, dire_team_id)`.  I would start with this latter index and see if that improves performance sufficiently for your purposes.