# How to Combine multiple column into one in php SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, multidimensional-array, phpmyadmin

[I have this data. Can someone help how can I combine them into one?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfpXh.png)

```
id  employeeID   date         timein    timeout     timein1     timeout1
1   12286        2016-09-10   08:08:00  00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00
2   12286        2016-09-10   00:00:00  12:08:32    00:00:00    00:00:00
3   12286        2016-09-10   00:00:00  00:00:00    12:41:54    00:00:00
4   12286        2016-09-10   00:00:00  00:00:00    00:00:00    17:10:05
5   12286        2016-10-10   07:41:05  00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00
6   12286        2016-10-10   00:00:00  12:15:00    00:00:00    00:00:00
7   12286        2016-10-10   00:00:00  00:00:00    12:35:15    00:00:00
8   12286        2016-10-10   00:00:00  00:00:00    00:00:00    17:15:15
```

[This is the output that I wanted. Help me. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06qvV.png)

```
id  employeeID   date         timein    timeout     timein1     timeout1
1   12286        2016-09-10   08:08:00  12:08:32    12:41:54    17:10:05
2   12286        2016-10-10   07:41:05  12:15:00    12:35:15    17:15:15
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what you already tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: Lots of people coming and going at midnight.

Comment: Also, id appears to be nonsensical in this result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Multiple child rows into one row MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067428/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd probably adopt a schema roughly as follows:

```
id  employeeID   datetime             activity
1   12286        2016-09-10 08:08:00  in 
2   12286        2016-09-10 12:08:32  out  
3   12286        2016-09-10 12:41:54  in
4   12286        2016-09-10 17:10:05  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution without field: id

select employeeID, date, max(timein), max(timeout), max(timein1), max(timeout1)
group by employeeID, date

Better revise the Insert query to null for 00:00:00 instead