# MySQL query where JOIN depends on CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

As I am now aware, CASE can be used only in WHERE context. Though, I need to use different table depending on `column` value. What I've tried looks like this:

```
SELECT
    `ft1`.`task`,
    COUNT(`ft1`.`id`) `count`
FROM
    `feed_tasks` `ft1`
CASE
    `ft1`.`type`
WHEN
    1
THEN
    (INNER JOIN `pages` `p1` ON `p1`.`id` = `ft1`.`reference_id`)
WHEN
    2
THEN
    (INNER JOIN `urls` `u1` ON `u1`.`id` = `ft1`.`reference_id`)
WHERE
    `ft1`.`account_id` IS NOT NULL AND
    `a1`.`user_id` = {$db->quote($user['id'])}
```

Now that I know this is invalid syntax, what's the closest alternative?

Comment: you should merge both `pages` and `urls`

Comment: Where did you read that CASE can only be used in WHERE clauses? It isn't true.

Comment: merge as in literally "merge two databases into one"? well, in that case this isn't an option because they both have completely different structure. @Álvaro G. Vicario: either way, this isn't valid syntax. Therefore I am asking for an alternative.

Comment: `merge two TABLES into one TABLE`,completely different? at least both tables having column `user_id` and `reference_id`, so where is the completely?

Comment: well, the other 10 columns, maybe?

Comment: Case statements can be use in both select and where clauses

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It probably needs tweaking to return the correct results but I hope you get the idea:

```
SELECT ft1.task, COUNT(ft1.id) AS count
FROM feed_tasks ft1
LEFT JOIN pages p1 ON ft1.type=1 AND p1.id = ft1.reference_id
LEFT JOIN urls u1 ON ft1.type=2 AND u1.id = ft1.reference_id
WHERE COALESCE(p1.id, u1.id) IS NOT NULL
AND ft1.account_id IS NOT NULL
AND a1.user_id = :user_id
```

**Edit:**

A little note about `CASE...END`. Your original code does not run because, unlike PHP or JavaScript, the SQL `CASE` is not a flow control structure that allows to choose which part of the code will run. Instead, it returns an expression. So you can do this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN foo<0 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END AS is_negative
FROM bar
```

... but not this:

```
-- Invalid
CASE 
    WHEN foo<0 THEN SELECT 'Yes' AS is_negative
    ELSE SELECT 'No' AS is_negative
END
FROM bar
```

Comment: it works fine with two left joins but when i add a third choice it return an error

Comment: @YosraNagati There's nothing in the join syntax that restricts it to a given number of tables. The error message is probably due to an error in your code.

Comment: I stand corrected: in MySQL you can only JOIN [61 tables at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684971/too-many-tables-mysql-can-only-use-61-tables-in-a-join).

Answer (score 1):

Use outer joins on both tables and move the `CASE` inside your `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    ft1.task,
    COUNT(case ft1.id when 1 then p1.id when 3 then u1.id end) as count
FROM feed_tasks ft1
LEFT JOIN pages p1 ON p1.id = ft1.reference_id
LEFT JOIN urls u1 ON u1.id = ft1.reference_id
WHERE ft1.account_id IS NOT NULL
AND a1.user_id = {$db->quote($user['id'])}
```

Non-hits for the `CASE` will give a `null` id and won't be counted.

Note: Table `a1` is in your where clause, but doesn't seem to be a selected table