# About Mysql join case when error

Tags: mysql, join, case

```
select t.* FROM user_tq t join 
CASE when t.blogid = 0 then user_dp ELSE  user_blog END b
on t.uid = b.uid where ***;
```

I want to join different table according to blogid, when blogid is 0, join user_dp, else join user_blog.But it returns `1064` error. 
How to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query where JOIN depends on CASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994843/mysql-query-where-join-depends-on-case)

Comment: b is your another table. RIGHT?

Comment: b is the alias of the join table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `left join` and filter the right result by `COALESCE`

```
select t.* 
FROM user_tq t 
left join user_dp ud on t.blogid = 0 and t.uid = ud.uid
left join user_blog ub on t.blogid != 0 and t.uid = ub.uid
where
COALESCE(ud.uid, ub.uid) IS NOT NULL and
***;
```

For more info refer : [MySQL query where JOIN depends on CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994843/mysql-query-where-join-depends-on-case)

If you are trying to `inner join to filter` data on condition then;

```
select * from (
    select t.* 
    FROM user_tq t 
    join user_dp ud on t.blogid = 0 and t.uid = ud.uid
    union all
    select t.* 
    FROM user_tq t 
    join user_blog ub on t.blogid != 0 and t.uid = ub.uid
) as x
where ****;
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE:**

```
select * FROM users t
left join user_role r ON t.user_id = 0 AND r.user_id = t.user_id
left join product_category c ON t.user_id != 0 AND c.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE COALESCE(r.user_id, c.user_id) IS NOT NULL
WHERE ***;
```

Replace users, user_role and product_category with your tables.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers posted here are the correct solutions.
I'll answer the "Why do I get 1064" for you.

The syntax you've written is invalid. You cannot "conditionally" join to a table like this.

What you *can* do is `LEFT JOIN` - which as opposed to `[INNER] JOIN` means "return `NULL` for all fields on this table if no record matches the join condition".

There's lots on the Internet about `LEFT` vs `INNER` joins, and MySQL's website documents the `COALESCE` function very well.

Have a play and a read, you'll figure it out why the other solutions work.

---

Upon reflection, I felt this could benefit from some additional explanation.

See this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/043b7/6