# Mysql many-to-many realtionship multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have three tables, for example:

watch table

```
id(int)  name(varchar)  ref(int)
1        tissot         1234567
2        addidas        7654321
3        nike           8976543
```

property table

```
id(int)  name(varchar)
1        water_resistant
2        material_body
3        material_bracelet
4        watch_type
```

property_material table

```
watch_id  property_id   value
1              1          200
1              2         steel
1              3         leather
1              4         quartz
2              1          50
2              2         plastic
2              3         leather
2              4         quartz
3              1         100
3              2         steel
3              3         rubber
3              4        mechanical
```

I want get all watches which have properties for example:

- water_resistant >= 100
- material_body = steel or plastic
- material_bracelet = leather or rubber
- watch_type = quartz.

Help me please create query. Properties can be about 100.
In ideal i want get result:

```
watch_id name    ref   water_res mat_body mat_bracelet watch_type
1        tissot  1234   200       steel    leather      quartz
```

I'm try:

```
select 
 w.*, pm.value,pm.property_id 
from 
 watch w 
join 
  property_material pm 
 on w.id = pm.watch_id 
where 
  pm.pid in (1,2,3) 
and 
 pm.value in ('100','Steel','Leather');
```

But this query return all records, when value is Steel or Leather, bur I need where material_body is Steel and material_bracelet is Leather, for example.

**UPDATE**: What you are think about this query?

```
select 
  name, ref 
from
  watch w
join
(SELECT w.id
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm on w.id = pm.watch_id
  WHERE (pm.property_id = 1 AND pm.value > 100)
   OR (pm.property_id = 2 AND pm.value IN ('steel','plastic'))
   OR (pm.property_id = 3 AND pm.value IN ('leather','rubber'))
   OR (pm.property_id = 4 AND pm.value = 'quartz')
  Group by w.id
  Having count(*) = 4) as t1
 on t1.id = w.id;
```

**LAST UPDATE**:

```
select 
  w.name, 
  max(if(pm.property_id='1',pm.value,'')) water_resistant,
  max(if(pm.property_id='2',pm.value,'')) material_body,
  max(if(pm.property_id='3',pm.value,'')) material_bracelet,
  max(if(pm.property_id='4',pm.value,'')) watch_type
from
  watch w
join
(
    SELECT w.id
  FROM watch w
       JOIN property_material pm on w.id = pm.watch_id
  WHERE (pm.property_id = 1 AND pm.value > 100)
      OR (pm.property_id = 2 AND pm.value IN ('steel','plastic'))
      OR (pm.property_id = 3 AND pm.value IN ('leather','rubber'))
      OR (pm.property_id = 4 AND pm.value = 'quartz')
  Group by w.id
  Having count(*) = 4
  ) as t1 on t1.id = w.id
 join property_material pm on w.id = pm.watch_id
GROUP BY w.id
```

Comment: Can you post a sample set of what you need as result? Do you have some code, have you tried something?

Comment: You are welcome but no need to thank. All the conditions should accomplished in one sentence or they are all independent?

Comment: Thank you for reply! 
I like get tuple: id, watch, ref, water_resistant, mateterial_body, material_braclet, watch_type. 
I'm try this: 
`select 
    w.*, pm.value,pm.pid
from 
    watch w
join 
    property_material pm    
on
    w.id = pm.watch_id
where 
   pm.pid in (1,2,3) and
   pm.value in ('100','Steel','Lather');` 
   - but this query return all records, when value is Steel or Leather.

Comment: Edit your question and add you code there, do not forget to format it for better understanding.

Comment: Your last query has a typo, should be `leather`, not `lather`. But I don't know if that is the result you need. [**Check here for test**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9587b/21)

Comment: Yaroslav, can i do grouping by watch_id, and get all result in one set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have several queries that fill your needs. But as you see, they are all independent. That is why I ask in the comments what exactly you need.

For more tests use this [**SQL Fiddle sample code**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9587b/9) using your provided sample data.

**EDIT** Added new query to have all conditions and all results on one set. Check [**SQL Fiddle sample code here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9587b/17).

```
SELECT w.name,ref,property_id,value 
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property p on w.id = p.id
  JOIN property_material pm on p.id = pm.property_id 
 WHERE (p.id = 1 AND pm.value > 100)
    OR (p.id = 2 AND pm.value IN ('steel','plastic'))
    OR (p.id = 3 AND pm.value IN ('leather','rubber'))
    OR (p.id = 4 AND pm.value = 'quartz');
```

Independent queries:

```
SELECT w.name Watch_name, p.name Property_name, pm.value Property_value
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm ON w.id = pm.watch_id
  JOIN property p ON p.id = pm.property_id
 WHERE p.id = 1
   AND pm.value > 100;

WATCH_NAME  PROPERTY_NAME     PROPERTY_VALUE
tissot      water_resistant   200
```

Another one:

```
SELECT w.name Watch_name, p.name Property_name, pm.value Property_value
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm ON w.id = pm.watch_id
  JOIN property p ON p.id = pm.property_id
 WHERE p.id = 2
   AND pm.value IN ('steel','plastic');

WATCH_NAME   PROPERTY_NAME   PROPERTY_VALUE
tissot      material_body      steel
addidas     material_body      plastic
nike        material_body      steel
```

Another one:

```
SELECT w.name Watch_name, p.name Property_name, pm.value Property_value
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm ON w.id = pm.watch_id
  JOIN property p ON p.id = pm.property_id
 WHERE p.id = 3
   AND pm.value IN ('leather','rubber');

WATCH_NAME   PROPERTY_NAME      PROPERTY_VALUE
tissot      material_bracelet      leather
addidas     material_bracelet      leather
nike        material_bracelet      rubber
```

Another one:

```
SELECT w.name Watch_name, p.name Property_name, pm.value Property_value
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm ON w.id = pm.watch_id
  JOIN property p ON p.id = pm.property_id
 WHERE p.id = 4
   AND pm.value = 'quartz';

WATCH_NAME   PROPERTY_NAME   PROPERTY_VALUE
tissot         watch_type       quartz
addidas        watch_type       quartz
```

Comment: Thanks, but in you result is Nike. Nike is mechanical watch. It is possible to make strict query, only: water_resistant >= 100, watch_type = quartz, material_body = steel or plastic and etc?

Comment: If i change  `OR (p.id = 4 AND pm.value = 'quartz123')`, result don't change.

Comment: That is because the watches on the result set already accomplish some of the previous conditions and even removing the last condition everything remains the same. That query was just to gather in one result set all the values, without any other restriction

Comment: What you think about this query: `select 
  name, ref 
from
  watch w
join
(SELECT w.id
  FROM watch w
  JOIN property_material pm on w.id = pm.watch_id
 WHERE (pm.property_id = 1 AND pm.value > 100)
    OR (pm.property_id = 2 AND pm.value IN ('steel','plastic'))
    OR (pm.property_id = 3 AND pm.value IN ('leather','rubber'))
    OR (pm.property_id = 4 AND pm.value = 'quartz')
Group by w.id
Having count(*) = 4) as t1
on t1.id = w.id` ?

Comment: Well, seems to be working, at least returns the result set you want. But test carefully, subqueries together with `group by` and `having`  can be tricky. Here is the [**SQL Fiddle code**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9587b/89) with your proposal, for you to test. I'm the middle of other things now, can't test, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility i know is to make a join to the properties table for each property, like so (i modified your given example):

```
select w.*, pm1.value,pm1.pid ,pm2.value,pm2.pid
    from watch w 
        join property_material pm1 on w.id = pm1.watch_id AND pm1.pid = 1 and pm1.value = '100'
        join property_material pm2 on w.id = pm2.watch_id AND pm2.pid = 2 and pm2.value IN ('Steel','Lather');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! If my condition consist by 20 properties, i can do 20 joins?

Comment: Yes, why not? But there is actually a limit of 61 tables for joins in MySQL. Your solution in the update feels better for me, there should be much more checks possible...

Comment: @vedmed I searched for further information for your problem; one nice answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685034/1338150. I hope that helps you...

Answer (score 0):

```
select watch_table.id,watch_table.name,ref,property_id,value from watch_table join        property_table on watch_table.id=property_table.id
  join property_material on property_table.id=property_material.property_id 
 where WHERE property.id = 3 AND property_material.value IN ('leather','rubber');
```