# Crosstab View in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I dont know I titled this correct, but let me explain what i am looking for.

I have two tables.

## **Clients**

```
clID   (primary key)
ClName (varchar)
```

## **Scores**

```
ID     (Primay key)
clID   (F Key)
PlayDate  (Date/Time)
Score     (double)
```

---

Client table data looks like this

```
clID  clName
1     Chris
2     Gale
3     Donna
```

Scores table data looks like this

```
ID  clID  PlayDate    Score
1   2     23/01/2012  -0.0125
2   2     24/01/2012  0.1011
3   3     24/01/2012  0.0002
4   3     26/01/2012  -0.0056
5   3     27/01/2012  0.0001
6   1     12/01/2012  0.0122
7   1     13/01/2012  0.0053
```

---

Is it possible to create a view that will look like this

```
Date         Chris   Gale    Donna
12/01/2012   0.0122   -        -
13/01/2012   0.0053   -        -
23/01/2012     -     -0.0125   -
24/01/2012     -     0.1011  0.0002
26/01/2012     -        -    -0.0056
27/01/2012     -        -    0.0001
```

If later there is a another new client then i should be able to check the data for that new client in the new column that will be now created in this view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to check this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852708/converting-mysql-resultset-from-rows-to-columns  OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336985/can-a-mysql-query-turn-rows-into-columns. The first one is good if the row-to-column values are known and the second one is you use GROUP_CONCAT but it will not make your rows into column actually.

Answer (score 6):

This type of data transformation is called a PIVOT. MySQL does not have a pivot function but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result.

If the names of the `clients` is known ahead of time, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select s.playdate,
  sum(case when clname = 'Chris' then score end) Chris,
  sum(case when clname = 'Gale' then score end) Gale,
  sum(case when clname = 'Donna' then score end) Donna
from clients c
inner join scores s
  on c.clid = s.clid
group by s.playdate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca16b/1).

If you have an unknown number of clients or you will be adding new clients that you will want included without having to change the code, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN clName = ''',
      clName,
      ''' THEN score else ''-'' END) AS `',
      clName, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM clients;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT s.playdate, ', @sql, ' 
            from clients c
            inner join scores s
              on c.clid = s.clid
            group by s.playdate');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca16b/3). Both queries will give the same result.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of a view.  May be there could be a procedure that deletes a view and recreates it view when a new client is added.

Comment: Awesome trick but with big table with a lot of data, it's too heavy :/

Comment: @Thermech I agree, with a large amount of data there are different ways that this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick 'crosstab' overview of the logins per hour, I use:

```
SELECT _d
, GROUP_CONCAT(LPAD(_cnt,4," ") ORDER BY _h SEPARATOR " ") AS `. 00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23` 
FROM (
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(last_access_epoch,"%Y-%m-%d") AS _d
  , FROM_UNIXTIME(last_access_epoch,"%H") AS _h
  , COUNT(*) AS _cnt 
  FROM login_log 
  WHERE last_access_epoch < 3600*(@@timestamp DIV 3600) /* before current hour */
  GROUP BY _d, _h
) AS t 
GROUP BY _d
HAVING MIN(_h)="00"  /* only full days */
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large amount of data for the GROUP_CONCAT example above, you may need to change your group_concat_max_len to avoid a syntax error due to truncation.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4096;
```

See: [Trouble with GROUP_CONCAT and Longtext in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529105/trouble-with-group-concat-and-longtext-in-mysql)