# Database tables with dynamic information

Tags: database-design

I've googled this and found that it's almost impossible to create a database with dynamic columns. I'll explain my problem first:

I am making a webshop for a customer. It has multiple computer products for sale. CPU's HDD's RAM etc. All these products have different properties, a CPU has an FSB, RAM has a CAS latency. But this is very inconvenient because my `orders` table needs foreign keys to different tables which is impossible.

An other option is to store all the product specific information in a varchar or blob field and let PHP figure it out. The problem with this solution is that the website needs a PC builder. A step-by-step guide to building your PC. So for instance if a customer decides he wants a new "i7 920" or whatever I want to be able to select all motherboards for socket 1366, which is impossible because all the data is stored in one field. I know it's possible to select all motherboards from the DB and let PHP figure out which ones are for socket 1366 but I was wondering,

is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951872/how-can-i-design-a-db-where-the-user-can-define-the-fields-and-types-of-a-detail/2952354#2952354) in order to figure out if that's the way you really want to go...  I'm not so sure.

The real issue is that you have highly related and very different components.  However, they do share properties in common...

So, let's say you have a ProductProperties table that looks something like

```
ProductId 
PropertyTypeId
PropertyId
Value
```

The products table should be something like:

```
ProductId
ProductCategoryId
Name
etc...
```

Assuming product 1 is a processor with a 1366 pin out, and product 2 is a motherboard with a 1366 socket, then each would have a Property of the "Socket" type with a value of 1366.  This would make it extremely easy to query for.  By querying the ProductProperties table (joining on Products), just exclude the ProductCategory of the item they are currently looking at to find products in other categories that work...  Or, if you know the category ahead of time (like motherboards) you just select that way.

You could go a little further on the admin side by defining Product Templates which automatically brought in the PropertyTypes at the time you are adding a new product.  They would simply select the template, fill in the values and save..

As a side note, I'm glad to know someone is working on a cart like this.  I love [newegg](http://www.newegg.com), but one thing I've felt they've always missed on is being able to link things like which processors will work with which motherboards.

Answer (score 2):

look at making tables like:

```
Products
ProductID      int     PK auto number/identity
ProductName    string
ProductType    char(1) FK to ProductTypes.ProductType
ProductCost
ProductPrice
...

HDDs
ProductID    int FK to Products.ProductID
HDDCapacity
HDDSpeed
....

RAMs
ProductID    int FK to Products.ProductID
RAMCapacity
RAMCASlatency
...

ProductTypes
ProductType             char(1)  PK  "H"=HDD, "R"=RAM, etc.
ProductTypeDescription  string
```

you have one main table with all the common columns, and one-to-one tables for the specific columns based on the ProductType column.  Your Orders table can now FK to Products.ProductID for all products.

Comment: The only other thing I would suggest is that you create a product type hierarchy (e.g. ProductType = MB-INTEL-1366, ProductFamily = MB).  Having a very specific type is necessary since you'll need to suggest compatible parts during the build process (e.g. If MB only supports IDE, you should only suggest IDE HDDs).  The general "family" groups like HD/RAM/VIDEO are nice for reporting & analysis but are not enough when building a system of compatible parts.

Comment: @Zachary, you make a very good point, but I only intended my answer to give a general approach to solve the issue and not give the exact final schema.

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic database you could consider the [EAV Database Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Search SO for EAV will also yield a good number of Q/As that closely address your particular conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is subclassing. One table will contain basic information relevant to all products. This is what you reference from the orders table. Then you can have other tables reference your products table and contain specific information based on the type of product. Something like:

```
               Orders
                  |
               Products
              /   |   \
           CPUs RAM Motherboards
```