# SQL - How to transpose?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, pivot

I have something similar to the following table:

```
================================================
| Id | UserId | FieldName     | FieldValue     |
=====+========+===============+================|
| 1  | 100    | Username      | John Doe       |
|----+--------+---------------+----------------|
| 2  | 100    | Password      | pass123!       |
|----+--------+---------------+----------------|
| 3  | 102    | Username      | Jane           |
|----+--------+---------------+----------------|
| 4  | 102    | Password      | $ecret         |
|----+--------+---------------+----------------|
| 5  | 102    | Email Address | jane@email.com |
------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that will give me a result like this:

```
==================================================
| UserId | Username  | Password | Email Address  |
=========+===========+===========================|
| 100    | John Doe  | pass123! |                |
|--------+-----------+----------+----------------|
| 102    | Jane      | $ecret   | jane@email.com |
|--------+-----------+----------+----------------|
```

Note that the values in FieldName are not limited to Username, Password, and Email Address. They can be anything as they are user defined.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema for a similar question. Is it impossible to do the pivoting in the application and leave the query straight forward? If you will need N attributes, you will need to generate the query dynamically.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support ANSI PIVOT/UNPIVOT syntax, so that leave you to use:

```
  SELECT t.userid
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Username' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Username,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Password' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Password,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Email Address' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Email
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.userid
```

As you can see, the CASE statements need to be defined per value.  To make this dynamic, you'd need to use [MySQL's Prepared Statement (dynamic SQL) syntax](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).

Comment: @KLee - So he doesn't have to group by those columns

Comment: @KLee1: Because the case statement doesn't flat the query - there'll be nulls in various spots.  So you have to use GROUP BY to flatten the query - MAX takes the highest value, and anything is higher than NULL.

Comment: +1. Tricky.  Wish I was good enough at MySQL to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

(untested)

```
SELECT UserId, 
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldname = 'Username', fieldvalue, NULL ) ) AS 'Username', 
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldname = 'Password', fieldvalue, NULL ) ) AS 'Password', 
GROUP_CONCAT( if( fieldname = 'Email Address', fieldvalue, NULL ) ) AS 'Email Address', 
FROM table  
GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: Risky because if the ELSE portion didn't return NULL, GROUP_CONCAT will return a comma delimited list.