# Make Meta_Key column headers

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pivot

totally new to MySQL and am trying to extract some data - I was expecting this to be a relatively simple task but I didnt realise that the "format" of the data extract wouldnt have the column headings i expected.  I've done some research and think I'm very close to the answer, provided here:

[SQL - How to transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose?answertab=votes#tab-top)

However, when writing my query I'm getting a syntax error.

So here is the code I've applied (using a little common sense to work out my specific values, although may have totally missed the mark!)

```
SELECT wp_usermeta.User_ID
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'nickname',
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'sex' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'sex'
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY wp_usermeta.User_ID
```

The error I'm getting is a #1064 advising to check the syntax on line 2 near 'MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE'

I'm sure this is a simple syntax error but i can't work it out!

Many thanks,

Stuart

Comment: Yeah, you're missing a comma. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Assuming you mean at the end of line 3 so it would be: MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'sex' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'sex',

Comment: @user3307899 try this `SELECT wp_usermeta.User_ID,
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'nickname',
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'sex' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'sex'
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY wp_usermeta.User_ID`

Comment: That's got it!  One comma, curses, that had me cross eyed for days!  Thank you!  Now to work out how to extract the returned data...

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can use WPDB class to retrieve results from raw query

```
global $wpdb;
$results=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT wp_usermeta.User_ID,
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'nickname',
   MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'sex' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'sex'
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY wp_usermeta.User_ID" );
if(!empty($results)){
foreach($results as $r){
echo $r->User_ID ."<br />";
echo $r->nickname ."<br />";
echo $r->sex ."<br />";
}
}
```

[**Wordpress Class WPDB**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Thanks for that Khalid - am happy enough with the missing comma answer above - it's exactly what i needed.

Comment: @user3307899 if above answer is helpfull then read [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

If you write your SELECTs this way, then that problem can never occur...

```
SELECT m.User_ID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'nickname' THEN m.meta_value END) nickname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'sex' THEN m.meta_value END) sex
  FROM wp_usermeta m
 GROUP 
    BY m.User_ID
```