# splitting the column fields into new columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-management

I need some help with some basic, i suppose, mysql.
given three columns such as the ones below:

```
[Events              Counts                Date
 play                    2                 2017/06/05
 pause                   3                 2017/06/05
 first quartile          4                 2017/06/05
 play                    10                2017/06/06
 pause                   12                2017/06/06][1]
```

How can I split the column `event` into new columns such `Play` column, `pause` columns and so on, having each of these new columns the relative data coming from the initial table?
Below you can find the link of what the resulting table should be looking like
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [transposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3392956/2298301)?

Comment: Show you desired output in a manner similar to how you've presented your sample source data.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena. Cheers. it's what i am looking for. Thanks Again

Comment: What query did you use to get those 3 columns? Add it to the question. Then, manually create the layout of that data that you want (called the "expected result")

Comment: The solution i got is not working. i'm gonna update the question with the expected end result i want to get