# separating values from single table then merge back

Tags: mysql

I'm tying to query if possible to separate the values into different columns using the same table

**so here is my sample table:**

select date, tool, value from table

```
+----------------------+-----------+-------+
|        date          |  tool     | value |  
|                      |           |       |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:38  |  machineA |   14  |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:39  |  machineA |   18  |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:40  |  machineB |   50  |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41  |  machineB |   50  |
+----------------------+-----------+-------+
```

**And trying to have output like this:**
    On my code I am looping this query then put in the dataset then re-organize the values, But now I'm not sure which function is reliable on this query should I need to do the joins or union or have some conditions.

```
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
|        date          |  machineA | machineB |  
|                      |           |          |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:38  |    14     |     0    |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:39  |    18     |     0    |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:40  |     0     |    50    |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41  |     0     |    50    |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
```

any suggestion and recommendation thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the values in `tool` column finite and fixed?

Comment: actually the column tool has 4 unique values only and that is machineA until machineD.

Comment: Then you have the answer here-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - How to transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose)

Comment: oh great! thanks I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below query, I have create a table as `t02`, you may have another name, just change it as yours.

```
mysql> select * from t02;
+---------------------+----------+-------+
| date                | tool     | value |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-03-11 13:03:39 | machineB |    50 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 | machineB |    50 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 | machineA |    14 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:42 | machineA |    18 |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

Let me show you how to do it step by step, first let try to pick up one!

```
select date, (tool='machineA') as machineA, (tool='machineB') as machineB from t02;

+---------------------+----------+----------+
| date                | machineA | machineB |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| 2017-03-11 13:03:39 |        0 |        1 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 |        0 |        1 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 |        1 |        0 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:42 |        1 |        0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+

select date, if((tool='machineA'), value, 0) as machineA, if((tool='machineB'), value, 0) as machineB from t02;
```

and then you should got the below result:

```
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| date                | machineA | machineB |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| 2017-03-11 13:03:39 |        0 |       50 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 |        0 |       50 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:41 |       14 |        0 |
| 2017-03-11 13:03:42 |       18 |        0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
```

If you have `machineC` and `machineD` , etc. you just do it with the same way will be fine `if((tool='machineX'), value, 0) as machineX`

Comment: Cool this is more shorter compare to my existing query and much readable, perfect!