# Create table from existing tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new table, based on two existing.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74e49
It must contain number of instances of every particular value from table1 in table2. Like:

- Name - koatuu1 - koatuu2 - koatuu3 - koatuu_N ... koatuu_350
- Johnson - 5 - 12 - 76 - 9 - 321 - 4

It must be something like this for every lastname:

```
select table1.koatuu, count(table2.*) 
from table2 
where lastname = "Johnson"
inner join table1 on table1.postcode = table2.postcode
```

[I need a red circled table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rw8q.png)
Can I do it within MySQL query, without writing a script in Php?

Comment: Provide us table structures, example data (no images) place it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/  like the help guide is telling https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ("How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.")
Also provide us with the expected output.

Comment: I'm doing it at the fist time, sorry. Is this it?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74e49

Comment: and what is your expected output for that sample fiddle? Edit the question with sample data and expected data

Comment: I assume now  looking into the sqlfiddle and the image you don't want to create a new table but a result based on the tables.. Besides this question is a duplicated search stackoverflow with "MySQL pivot" or "MySQL convert records into columns" or if you need it to be dynamic "MySQL dynamic pivot"

Answer (score 0):

The red table has 2 columns (`lastname` and `koatuu`). To get all the `koatuu` values for each `lastname` use this query

```
SELECT lastname,GROUP_CONCAT(koatuu) FROM lastname_koatuu GROUP BY lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to transpose rows to columns

MySQL doesn't support ANSI PIVOT/UNPIVOT syntax, so that leave you to use [MySQL's Prepared Statement (dynamic SQL) syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

You may use CASE for each row, like in [SQL Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose)