# What is the best way to make a new column from pre-existing rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks like this:

| thing | date | date_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/12 | start_date |
| 1 | 1/14 | end_date |
| 2 | 2/14 | start_date |
| 2 | 2/15 | end_date |

And I'm trying to compress everything down to look like this:

| thing | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/12 | 1/14 |
| 2 | 2/14 | 2/15 |

What is the best way to write this query? I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm not sure what the best way to word this is. I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT thing, date AS start_date, date AS end_date
FROM t1 ON...
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, I'm just unfamiliar with SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - How to transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose)

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select thing,
       max(case when data_type = 'start_date' then date end) as start_date,
       max(case when data_type = 'end_date' then date end) as end_date
from t
group by thing;
```