# How can I implement an SQL query that starting from a query returning multiple records return a single records with multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot-table, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem working on a **MySql** database.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CommodityName (
  id                   BigInt(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  commodity_details_id BigInt(20) NOT NULL,
  language_id          BigInt(20) NOT NULL,
  commodity_name       VarChar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  description          Text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=87 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
ALTER TABLE CommodityName COMMENT = '';
```

The records in this table represents commodities information in different languages.

The commodity is specified by the **univocally** by the **commodity_details_id** (that is a FK of another table).

A specific commodity can have multiple record into this **CommodityName** table (I have a record for each translation in a specific language, represented by the **language_id** field). For example I have these 2 records:

```
id                   commodity_details_id language_id          commodity_name          description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    1                    1                    Rice Asia               Rice Asia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
16                   1                    3                    Umuceli Asia            Umuceli Asia
```

that represents the same commodities information (both having **commodity_details_id=1**) but in 2 languages (English and Kinirwanda language). In theory I can have also other languages, so I can have n records for a specific commodity.

I need to create a query where for a specified commodity (**WHERE commodity_details_id=1**) it returns all the **commodity_name** fields of the retrieved record as column of a single record.

Referring to the previous example something like this:

```
commodity_details_id       commodity_name_EN      commodity_name_RWA          commodity_name_FR   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                          Rice Asia              Umuceli Asia                null
```

How can I implement a query like this that from multiple records transform a part of the information in each records as a new column in the new query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Crosstab/Pivot Query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920626/is-it-possible-to-use-crosstab-pivot-query-in-mysql)

Comment: You've picked the wrong primary key for your table.

Comment: which db version  your are using?

Comment: Do you have a languages table as well? And do you want to have a column for every possible language in your language table or only those languages which appear in the commodityname table

Comment: The data-analysis jargon for your requirement is **pivoting** your table, for what it's worth.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes the language_id field contains an FK to a Language table that is a typoligical table containing the allowed language in the system

Comment: @O.Jones what do you mean?

Comment: Would you like to answer the second part of my comment?

Comment: My comment about the word *pivoting* is intended to give you another way of searching for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT commodity_details_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN language_id=1 then commodity_name else null END) commodity_name_EN,
MAX(CASE WHEN language_id=3 then commodity_name else null END) commodity_name_RWA,
MAX(CASE WHEN language_id=2 then commodity_name else null END) commodity_name_FR
FROM CommodityName
group by commodity_details_id;
```

Comment: It is not working, I am obtaining this error message:
#42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') commodity_name_EN, MAX(CASE WHEN language_id=3 then commodity_name else null)' at line 2

Comment: ... and `SELECT`s need `FROM`s.

Comment: It does not work in case of more than 3 languages assigned to same commodity_details_id. Hence It is static.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called ***Dynamic Pivot***.

Look at the below code and see if it works for you. Schema might be little different in your case(just names of columns and tables).
I am using commodityName, commodity_details, languages table.
All you need to do is pass a commodity_details_id in parameter at 2nd line:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @commodity_details_id = 1;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN language_id = ''',
      ID,
      ''' then ''',
      (select commodity_name from commodityname where language_id = L.Id and commodity_details_id = @commodity_details_id),
      ''' end) AS ',
      Concat('Commodity_Name','_', language_name)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from languages L;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
'SELECT commodity_details_id, '
, @sql, 
' 
FROM CommodityName
where commodity_details_id = ',@commodity_details_id,'
group by commodity_details_id;
');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You can also create a stored routine out of this to call it from application or something.

Please comment if it doesn't work for you.