# How to Join and Pivot a Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I have 3 tables. I need to join 2 of them and have the join pivot the joined table to return the values in the row. Read below for clarification.

```
Table 1:
t1ID   Title
01     Title 1
01_01  Title 1a
01_02  Title 1b
01_03  Title 1c
02     Title 2
02_01  Title 2a
02_02  Title 2b
```

... and so on

```
Table 2 (not used in my join, but shown to see relationship between 3 tables -- contains a fixed number of rows which is 10):
t2ID  Description
01    Desc A
02    Desc B
03    Desc C
...
10    Desc J


Table 3:
t1ID   t2ID  Value
01     01    A
01     02    B
...
01     10    C
01_01  01    D
01_01  02    E
...
02_01  10    F
02_02  01    G
02_02  02    H
```

...and so on

I want to join Table 1 and Table 3 on `t1ID` where Table 1 is the main or master and Table 3 provides detailed values. I need to order Table 3 on `t2ID` to keep the sequence so I can handle the output properly.

I would like the query results to look like this:

```
row[0]    row[1]  row[2] ... row[10]
Title 1   A       B          C
Title 1a  D       E
```

So I need each row to have the 1st item in the output array as the title and then items 2 through 11 of the output array coming from the join Table 3.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks for helping me on this.

**AMENDED (Getting closer, or at least I no longer have the derived alias error message):**

```
SELECT t1.t1ID, t1.Title, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.Value) AS value
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t3.t1ID = t1.t1ID
GROUP BY t3.t1ID
ORDER BY t1.t1ID
```

All I need to do now is have Table 3 sorted in t2ID ORDER

Can anyone assist with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort `group_concat()` output as follows:

```
SELECT
    t1.t1ID,
    t1.Title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t3.Value order by t2ID) AS value
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t3.t1ID = t1.t1ID
GROUP BY t3.t1ID
ORDER BY t1.t1ID
```

Notice the `order by` *within* the `group_concat()` call.

Comment: Actually, I need to sort the t2ID column on Table3 and not the Values column @Bohemian

Comment: So I changed your targeted ORDER BY column -- and IT WORKED !!! Awesome. Thanks @Bohemian

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian...I was one of the users who already upvoted your answer

Comment: Oh cool. Still, it would help me if you up voted the accepted answer too (it's a badge thing)

Comment: I just tried voting the answer and got this message "You last voted on this answer 5 hours ago Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" so it did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that easily with MySQL, but the `GROUP_CONCAT` function will probably work for you.  The query would look like this:

```
SELECT Title, GROUP_CONCAT(Value) AS values
FROM Table1 AS t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT t1ID, Value FROM Table3 ORDER BY t2ID ASC
    ) AS t2 USING(t1ID)
GROUP BY t1ID
```

The result of this query will be something like

```
Title    | values
---------|-------
Title 1  | A,B,C
Title 1a | D,E
```

You should then be able to explode the string of values into an array.  If you absolutely have to actually pivot the data, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078983/is-there-a-way-to-pivot-rows-to-columns-in-mysql-without-using-case) has more helpful information.

Edit: Bohemian is correct and his method is better than mine since it uses a `JOIN` instead of a sub-query.

Comment: Thanks G-Nugget,exploding will work for what I need to so. I will try your solution and post back. Thanks again

Comment: I am testing now -- I got the following error message `Every derived table must have its own alias` @G-Nugget ... I am looking into it

Comment: I have added an `AS ...` to both `FROM` statements and I still get the error message `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: I have amended my initial question with some code I am getting to work. I just need to have a sort order on Table 3. Thanks @G-Nugget

Comment: @H.Ferrence Yeah, that error you got is true.  I'm updating my question with aliases for the tables that should fix the error.  Adding the second table as a sub-query is not optimal, but is required since the data on it has to be ordered before it gets joined.