# Pivot MySQL rows to columns in view

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have the following tables: days, periods, prices, brands, vehicles.

The Price model belongsTo Day and Period.

DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `low` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `high` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `periods` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `finish` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `brands` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `size_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_specs` text,
  `specs` text,
  `publish` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicle_id` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `day_id` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `period_id` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I'm using virtualFields for the Day and Period models:

```
// day.php
var $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => "CONCAT(Day.low,IF(Day.high IS NULL, '+', ' to '),IF(Day.high IS NULL, '', Day.high))"
);

// period.php  dates are localized using setLocale and strftime in afterFind()
var $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => "CONCAT(Period.start,'|', Period.finish)"
);
function afterFind($results) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['Period']['name'])) {
            $dates = explode('|',$val['Period']['name']);
            $results[$key]['Period']['name'] = strftime('%d %b %Y',strtotime($dates[0])). ' – ' . strftime('%d %b %Y',strtotime($dates[1]));
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

In the Price model if I do:

```
function price($id) {
    $this->set('prices', $this->find('all',array('conditions' => ('Price.vehicle_id' => $id))));
}
```

This is shown in the view

```
Day            Period                      Price
5 - 20          01 May 2011 to 31 Aug 2011  $87.00
21 to 27        01 May 2011 to 31 Aug 2011  $66.00
28+             01 May 2011 to 31 Aug 2011  $63.00
5 - 20          01 Sep 2011 to 30 Sep 2011  $177.00
21 to 27        01 Sep 2011 to 30 Sep 2011  $165.00
28+             01 Sep 2011 to 30 Sep 2011  $155.00
5 - 20          01 Oct 2011 to 31 Oct 2011  $322.00
21 to 27        01 Oct 2011 to 31 Oct 2011  $310.00
28+             01 Oct 2011 to 31 Oct 2011  $300.00
```

How can I present the data like this?

```
                           5 - 20 days     21 - 27 days    28+ days
01 May 2011 to 31 Aug 2011  $87.00      $66.00      $63.00
01 Sep 2011 to 30 Sep 2011  $177.00         $165.00         $155.00
01 Oct 2011 to 31 Oct 2011  $322.00         $310.00         $300.00
```

I have been trying to learn about [pivot tables](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78) but am struggling to do this in CakePHP.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Story wrote a blog post titled ["Creating easy reports with pivot tables"](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/creating-easy-reports-with-pivot-tables), which will most likely help you. The essential piece is to create a separate field in the query for each column you want, then use an expression for the field with an `IF` to select only those rows that should be used in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.  This was helpful: [How to pivot a MySQL entity-attribute-value schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema/652748#652748)

```
$prices = $this->Price->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Price.vehicle_id'=>$id
    ),
    'fields'=>( //GROUP_CONCAT days and prices and separate with colon
        "GROUP_CONCAT( 
            CONCAT_WS(':',
                CONCAT(`Day`.`low`,IF(`Day`.`high` IS NULL, '+', ' to '),IF(`Day`.`high` IS NULL, '', `Day`.`high`)),
                `Price`.`price`
            )
            ORDER BY `Day`.`low`
        ) AS prices, 
        (CONCAT(`Period`.`start`,'|', `Period`.`finish`)) AS `period_name`"
    ),
    'group' => 'Period.id',
    'order' => 'Period.start'
    )
);
```

$prices looks like:

```
array(
    array(
        array(
            'prices' => 'days:price,days:price,days:price,days:price...',
            'period_name' => 'yyy-mm-dd|yyyy-mm-dd'
        ),
        ...
```