# Sql: Transposing rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Consider the example below where I have a **Person** table containing person records and a **PersonAttribute** table which contains optional attributes linked to a person:

**Table: Person**

```
ID    Name
1     Joe Bloggs
2     Jane Doe
```

**Table PersonAttribute**

```
PersonId  Key         Value
1         Age         27            
2         HairColor   Brown
```

How would I write a query that returns all people with the attributes as if they were columns?  The resultset I require is:

```
ID    Name        Age    HairColor
1     Joe Bloggs  27     
2     Jane Doe           Brown
```

So essentially I need to write a query that gets all Person Records with all unique Attribute Keys transposed as columns with the value for each person record.

Note that the primary key on the **PersonAttribute** table is **PersonID** and **Key** combined so we wont have duplicate entries for a specific key and person.

Obviously I could add the **Age** and **HairColor** as fields in the **Person** table and not use the **PersonAttribute** table at all, but this is just an example to illustrate the problem.  In reality I have a huge number of custom attributes that vary wildly for different person records so it is not practical to do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak about MySQL, but in PostgreSQL you could use crosstab function from [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) module:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PersonAttributePivot AS
    SELECT PersonId AS ID, Age, HairColor
    FROM crosstab
    (
       'SELECT PersonId, Key, Value FROM PersonAttribute',
       'SELECT DISTINCT Key FROM PersonAttribute ORDER BY Key'
    )
    AS
    (
        PersonId integer,
        Age text,
        HairColor text
    );
```

Join query:

```sql
SELECT id, name, age, haircolor
FROM Person JOIN PersonAttributePivot USING(id)
ORDER BY id;
```

Wanted result:

```
 id |    name    | age | haircolor 
----+------------+-----+-----------
  1 | Joe Bloggs | 27  | 
  2 | Jane Doe   |     | Brown
(2 rows)
```

As you see I put explicit list of columns in `PersonAttributePivot` view. I don't know any "automatic-pivot" creation way with implicit column list.

**EDIT:**

For **huge** column list (assuming always `text` type) as a workaround I see such little modified approach:

#### Dynamic type creation (here trivially Java based):

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection c =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres", "postgres", "12345");
Statement s = c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Key FROM PersonAttribute ORDER BY Key");
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next())
    columns.add(rs.getString(1));

System.out.println("CREATE TYPE PersonAttributePivotType AS (");
System.out.println("\tPersonId integer,");
for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); ++i)
{
    System.out.print("\t" + columns.get(i) + " text");
    if (i != columns.size() - 1)
        System.out.print(",");
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(");");
```

Result:

```
CREATE TYPE PersonAttributePivotType AS (
    PersonId integer,
    Age text,
    HairColor text
);
```

#### Function wrapper:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crosstabPersonAttribute(text, text)
    RETURNS setof PersonAttributePivotType
    AS '$libdir/tablefunc','crosstab_hash' LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;
```

#### Automatic view creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PersonAttributePivot AS
    SELECT * FROM crosstabPersonAttribute
    (
       'SELECT PersonId, Key, Value FROM PersonAttribute',
       'SELECT DISTINCT Key FROM PersonAttribute ORDER BY Key'
    );
```

Result:

```
TABLE PersonAttributePivot;
 personid | age | haircolor
----------+-----+-----------
        1 | 27  |
        2 |     | Brown
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Process of transforming row-based dataset in column-based dataset is called pivoting. You might get some insight in how to do it at this link: [How to pivot a MySQL entity-attribute-value schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema)