# Dynamically generate columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

I have seen that there are quit a few similar questions like this one, but I havent understood how to code it myself. Please have in mind that I am just a beginner in this field.

Basically I want to pivot the table like this:

```
zoom |    day     | point         zoom | 2015-10-01 |  2015-10-02 | ......
------+-----------+-------  ---> ------+------------+-------------+
   1 | 2015-10-01 |   201            1 |    201     |     685     |
   2 | 2015-10-01 |    43            2 |     43     |     346     | 
   3 | 2015-10-01 |    80            3 |     80     |     534     | 
   4 | 2015-10-01 |   324            4 |    324     |     786     | 
   5 | 2015-10-01 |    25            5 |     25     |     685     |
   1 | 2015-10-02 |   685 
   2 | 2015-10-02 |   346 
   3 | 2015-10-02 |   534 
   4 | 2015-10-02 |   555 
   5 | 2015-10-02 |   786
   :
   :
   :
```

Time can vary.

Results on left I get with:

```
SELECT 
zoom,
to_char(date_trunc('day', time), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day,
count(*) as point
FROM province
WHERE time >= '2015-05-01' AND time < '2015-06-01'
GROUP BY to_char(date_trunc('day', time), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), zoom;
```

I have read that there are some issues if I use `count` and also that it would be better if I use `CASE` and `GROUP BY`, however I have no idea how to `CASE` this.

`Crosstab` itself doesnt support dynamic creation of column names, but that can be achieved with `crosstab_hash`, if I understood it correctly.

This might be probably nice solution: http://okbob.blogspot.ca/2008/08/using-cursors-for-generating-cross.html however I am stucked with it trying to program it myself.

I have to use this kind of pivoting quite often, so I would appriciate any  kind of help and additional explanation behind it.

**Edit1**

I am trying to figure out how crosstab works with dates, currently without returning dynamic names of columns. Later on I will explain why. It is realted to the main question. For this example I am using only period of 2 dates.

Based on @Erwin Brandstetter answer:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT zoom, day, point
        FROM   province
        ORDER  BY 1, 2'
      , $$VALUES ('2015-10-01'::date), ('2015-10-02')$$)
AS ct (zoom text, day1 int, day2 int);
```

returned results are:

```
zoom |    day1    |    day2     | 
-----+------------+-------------+
   1 |    201     |     685     |
   2 |     43     |     346     | 
   3 |     80     |     534     | 
   4 |    324     |     786     |
```

I am trying to get this

```
zoom | 2015-10-01 |  2015-10-02 | 
-----+------------+-------------+
   1 |    201     |     685     |
   2 |     43     |     346     | 
   3 |     80     |     534     | 
   4 |    324     |     786     |
```

but my query doesnt work:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT *
       FROM province
       ORDER  BY 1,2')
AS ct (zoom text, "2015-10-01" date, "2015-10-02" date);

ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
```

**Edit1, Q1. Why does this doesnt work and how can I return results like that?**

I have read links that @Erwin Brandstetter provided me, especially this one: [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103). I have copied/pasted his function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pivottab(_tbl regclass, 
                                    _row text, _cat text, 
                                    _expr text,
                                    _type regtype)  
RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _cat_list text;
   _col_list text;
BEGIN
-- generate categories for xtab param and col definition list    
EXECUTE format(
 $$SELECT string_agg(quote_literal(x.cat), '), (')
        , string_agg(quote_ident  (x.cat), %L)
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT %I AS cat FROM %s ORDER BY 1) x$$
 , ' ' || _type || ', ', _cat, _tbl)
INTO  _cat_list, _col_list;

-- generate query string
RETURN format(
'SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $q$SELECT %I, %I, %s
      FROM   %I
      GROUP  BY 1, 2
      ORDER  BY 1, 2$q$
 , $c$VALUES (%5$s)$c$
   ) ct(%1$I text, %6$s %7$s)'
, _row, _cat, _expr, _tbl, _cat_list, _col_list, _type
);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and call it with query

```
SELECT pivottab('province','zoom','day','point','date');
```

Function returned me:

```
                         pivottab                         
----------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT * FROM crosstab(                                 +
    $q$SELECT zoom, day, point                           +
       FROM   province                                   +
       GROUP  BY 1, 2                                    +
       ORDER  BY 1, 2$q$                                 +
  , $c$VALUES ('2015-10-01'), ('2015-10-02')$c$          +
    ) ct(zoom text, "2015-10-01" date, "2015-10-02" date)
(1 row)
```

So when I edited the query and added ; (it would be nice that ; is already there) I got:

```
ERROR:  column "province.point" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

**Edit1, Q2. Any ideas how to solove this?**

**Edit1, Q3. I guess next question will be how to execute function automaticlly**, which is also mentioned on the same link, but got stucked on previous steps.

Comment: Build up your dynamic SQL with looping over a record and appending to the string that hold up your query. This can be achieved using `plpgsql`. Then return a table from the function and you are good to go :-)

Comment: What's supposed to be dynamic? Number of result columns? Names or data types of result columns?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry, I just added dots to the table. So I need to add dynamically names of the columns...it would be like 2015-10-01, 2015-10-02, 2015-10-03, 2015-10-04 ... depending on a WHERE part in first query. That should be generated without listing them manually, because sometimes I might have for example interval of 75 days

Answer (score 4):

The basic crosstab query for your example is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT zoom, day, point
        FROM   province
        ORDER  BY 1, 2'

     , $$VALUES ('2015-10-01'::date), ('2015-10-02')$$)
AS ct (zoom text, day1 int, day2 int);
```

But ***not*** with dynamic column names or a dynamic number of columns.
As a compromise, you can have a fixed number of columns and only fill the leading ones. Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

#### Dynamic?

`crosstab_hash` is not going to help you with dynamic column names. It's for repeated use without typing a column definition list, but not for *dynamic* column names. Examples:

- [Dynamically generate columns for crosstab in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879672/dynamically-generate-columns-for-crosstab-in-postgresql/12887645#12887645)
- [Sql: Transposing rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680070/sql-transposing-rows-into-columns/6681044#6681044)

For truly dynamic column names, you need *two* round trips to the server. Whether you retrieve the column names with a first query to build a second query, or you create a cursor or a temporary table or a prepared statement. Whatever you try, you need two round trips. SQL wants to know the return type at call time.

The closest I could get to a "dynamic" call is with my custom `crosstab_n()` function defined in this related answer:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

---

Or you give up the idea of a completely dynamic crosstab query (because, you know, it's impossible) and use a two-step workflow, like mentioned above.

1. Let a function generate the crosstab query text. You can use the function provided here (and adapt it to your needs!):

   - [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103)

   <sub>In particular, remove `GROUP  BY 1, 2`, since you do not aggregate rows before the cross tabulation.</sub>
2. Execute the generated function.

---

For completeness, there is also the new [`\crosstabview` metacommand in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html) in Postgres **9.6** (just released) - with similar functionality, and it can display dynamic column names (attaching dynamic names happens in the psql client, not in the Postgres server).

Comment: Thanks, I will go through all this links thoroughly tomorrow. So basically you are saying that its hard to return dynamically columns like that and I should look for some other solution?

Comment: Completely dynamic columns are strictly impossible in SQL. Your way around this limitation depends on your requirements. I added one more alternative above: use a two-step workflow instead ...

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I got stucked on baby steps. Please take a look at my edited question under Edit1!

Comment: @newbie_girl: Adapt the function to your needs. I added some hints above. You need a basic understanding of  what you are doing. Please ask any new questions as new question.

Comment: Sorry, thought it would be inapproriate to open a new subject. thanks for additional instruction. but I guess I will have to ask new questions.

Comment: @newbie_girl: This is a Q/A site. Well formulated questions are always welcome

Comment: crosstab function i am not able to use it. Please let me know why I am getting error while using it.

Comment: I have a requirement of creating a table based on cursor column values as columns in that create table. Is it possible to achieve it ?