# PostgreSQL crosstab with dynamic column names and multiple input columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, entity-attribute-value

## Problem

I've got a PostgreSQL 9.6 database with a table designed according to an EAV model with different types of values. An example excerpt looks like this:

```
 name |arrivalTime | boolValue | intValue | floatValue | stringValue
------+------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------
 a1   |  10:00:00  |   true    |          |            |
 c3   |  10:00:00  |           |   12     |            |
 d4   |  10:00:00  |           |          |            | hello
 e5   |  15:00:00  |           |          |    45.67   |
 c3   |  15:00:00  |           |   45     |            |
 b2   |  20:00:00  |           |          |    4.567   |
 a1   |  20:00:00  |   false   |          |            |
 d4   |  22:00:00  |           |          |            |  bye
 b2   |  22:00:00  |           |          |    12.34   |
```

Empty cells represent `null` values in the database.

Now I would like to get a Pivot table, were the new columns are the `arrivalTime` and the content of `name`. For the example from above it should look like this:

```
arrivalTime |  a1   |  b2   |  c3   |  d4   |  e5
------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
  10:00:00  | true  |       |  12   | hello |
  15:00:00  |       |       |  45   |       | 45.67
  20:00:00  | false | 4.567 |       |       |
  22:00:00  |       | 12.34 |       |  bye  |
```

As an input to query for retrieving this result I get an pattern matching the `name`s and a start and end time specifying the range of `arrivalTime`.

Properties of the original table:

- The entries in the name column are volatile, i.e. new names come in
  and old names vanish regularly.
- Each combination of `name` and `arrivalTime` is unique.
- Each `name` and `arrivalTime` combination has exactly one entry in one of the value columns.

## Ideas

I already gave it some considerations:

- I figured so much, that the `crosstab` function should be used
- Since the columns are dynamic, two queries will be needed as explained in [Dynamically generate columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779734/dynamically-generate-columns-in-postgresql) or [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query).
- Using the `format()` function to generate the first query is probably a good idea.

## Example Table

Here is the SQL Code to create the example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playTable (
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  arrivalTime TIME NOT NULL,
  floatValue REAL NULL,
  intValue INT NULL,
  boolValue BOOLEAN NULL,
  stringValue TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, arrivalTime),
  CONSTRAINT single_value CHECK(
    (boolValue IS NOT NULL)::INT + 
    (intValue IS NOT NULL)::INT + 
    (floatValue IS NOT NULL)::INT +
    (stringValue IS NOT NULL)::INT = 1
  )
);
```

And to insert the values:

```
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, boolValue ) VALUES ( 'a1', '10:00:00', true );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, intValue ) VALUES ( 'c3', '10:00:00', 12 );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, stringValue ) VALUES ( 'd4', '10:00:00', 'hello' );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, floatValue ) VALUES ( 'e5', '15:00:00', 45.67 );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, intValue ) VALUES ( 'c3', '15:00:00', 45 );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, floatValue ) VALUES ( 'b2', '20:00:00', 4.567 );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, boolValue ) VALUES ( 'a1', '20:00:00', false );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, stringValue ) VALUES ( 'd4', '22:00:00', 'bye' );
INSERT INTO playTable ( name, arrivalTime, floatValue ) VALUES ( 'b2', '22:00:00', 12.34 );
```

## Pivot table, non dynamic

[klin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43872818/711270)  provided the starting point of the solution, I guess:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    $ct$
        SELECT 
            arrivalTime, name, concat(boolValue, intValue, floatValue, stringValue)
        FROM playTable
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    $ct$,
    $ct$
        SELECT DISTINCT name 
        FROM playTable
        ORDER BY 1
    $ct$) 
AS ct("arrivalTime" time, "a1" BOOLEAN, "b2" REAL, "c3" INT, "d4" TEXT, "e5" REAL);
```

What is missing from this solution is the dynamic aspect. As an input, a `LIKE` pattern for `name` is supplied and the range (i. e. min and max value) of `arrivalTime`. This makes the argument of `as ct(...)` dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce()` for four last columns. You have to cast the columns to `text` to do this:

```
select *
from crosstab(
    $ct$
        select 
            arrivaltime, name, 
            coalesce(boolvalue::text, intvalue::text, floatvalue::text, stringvalue)
        from my_table
        order by 1, 2
    $ct$,
    $ct$
        select distinct name 
        from my_table
        order by 1
    $ct$) 
as ct("arrivalTime" time, "a1" text, "b2" text, "c3" text, "d4" text, "e5" text);

 arrivalTime |  a1   |  b2   | c3 |  d4   |  e5   
-------------+-------+-------+----+-------+-------
 10:00:00    | true  |       | 12 | hello | 
 15:00:00    |       |       | 45 |       | 45.67
 20:00:00    | false | 4.567 |    |       | 
 22:00:00    |       | 12.34 |    | bye   | 
(4 rows)
```

I have used `arrivalTime time` because of the format of the example data, change it to `timestamp`.

Comment: I played around with solution and extended my question a bit. I changed your code from using `coalesce` to `concat`.

This works fine and important hurdles are taken, but I'm not at the finish yet:
Still missing is the ability to put in the pattern specifying the `name` and the `arrivalTime` range. This makes the argument of `as ct(...)` dynamic.

Comment: user711270 You need any kind of programming languge, that will generate SQL queries for you, taking care of input patterns. If you are in SQL only use plpgsql to create such dynamic queries.