# Is there a way to create a dynamic number of columns in a plpgsql function return value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following SQL code:

```sql
SELECT
    dip
    || ' '
    || (
        SELECT lib1 || ' ' || lib2
        FROM bds
        WHERE dip_s = dip
    ) AS label,
    COUNT(dip) AS freq
FROM current_table
WHERE v_deg = '3'
GROUP BY dip;
```

This code outputs a columns for the label, and another column for the number of occurence where `v_deg='3'`.
The issue I have however is that I have multiple values of `v_deg` (a variable number of columns) and I need to add their respective column to the result.

I would have the following columns.

```
label|freq(v_deg='1')|freq(v_deg='2')|freq(v_deg='3')|freq(v_deg='4')|...
```

Since having a dynamic number of columns is not possible in basic SQL, I looked at plpgsql tutorials but I am clearly a beginner. Here's my try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_REM_T4(current_table text)
RETURNS SETOF record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    col_name text;
BEGIN
    FOR col_name IN 
        SELECT DISTINCT v_deg FROM current_table
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT dip || '' '' || (
            SELECT lib1 || '' '' || lib2
            FROM bds
            WHERE dip_s = '||current_table.dip||'
            AND v_deg = '||col_name||
            ' )'
        INTO col_name;
        
        RETURN NEXT (col_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

The previous function outputs the following error when I put the correct parameter:

```
ERROR:  relation "current_table" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT v_deg FROM current_table
```

I would like to know how to modify my function to get the desired ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/pgSQL is just an extension of SQL. A function has to be called in an SQL statement, and the number, types, and names of returned columns must be known or declared at call time at the latest.

**There are limited workarounds, but none works for your objective.**

You could create the function with `RETUNRS SETOF record`. Or you could use polymorphism. But either only postpones the inevitable. Then you have to declare the return type with a column definition list or pass a row type in the call. But that only becomes evident *after* processing your query. Catch 22. I don't see how either could help you.

See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Return an array column, or return multiple rows (one per distinct `v_deg`), or return a document type like `json`, `jsonb`, `hstore` or `xml`.

**Or** do two round trips to the DB server. One to determine the return type, and a second one with an according column definition list for your `RETURNS SETOF record` function, or with a matching row type for your polymorphic function. See:

- [Return SETOF rows from PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864911/return-setof-rows-from-postgresql-function/17865708#17865708)

Also, what you are trying to do is rally a dynamic "crosstab" or "pivot" operation. See:

- [Dynamically generate columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779734/dynamically-generate-columns-in-postgresql/39782514#39782514)