# How to Display rows as Columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rows

Guys I've table called **beneficiaryloans** as follows

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| id | beneficiary_id | hfi_id | amount | rate | period | status_id |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
| 15 |             37 |    116 |    123 |  123 |    123 |         4 |
| 16 |             38 |    117 |    123 |  123 |    123 |         4 |
| 17 |             39 |    116 |    123 |  123 |    123 |         4 |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+------+--------+-----------+
```

I want to Display It as follows based on **Hfi_id**

```
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| beneficiary_id  | hfi_id_116 | hfi_id_117   |
+-----------------+----------------------------
| 37              |  True      |    False     |
| 38              |  False     |    True      |
| 39              |  True      |    False     |
+----------------------------------------------
```

How to do this in MySQL?

**Note:** Here I posted some of rows, and **hfi_ids** are keep stamping in this table, if **3 hfi_id** then i need **3 columns**, if 4 **hfi_ids** then i need **4 columns** and so on

Comment: You are looking for PIVOT. Unfortunately, MySQL does not support this, but there are workarounds. Try searching Stackoverflow for MySQL PIVOT, or look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema

Comment: It is really interesting puzzle to realize what you want. Could you please attach rules how to produce columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT beneficiary_id, 
  CASE hfi_id
      WHEN 116 THEN true
      ELSE false
  END AS hfi_id_116,
  CASE hfi_id
      WHEN 117 THEN true
      ELSE false
  END AS hfi_id_117
FROM your_table
```

or if you need strings

```
SELECT beneficiary_id, 
  CASE hfi_id
      WHEN 116 THEN 'True'
      ELSE 'False'
  END AS hfi_id_116,
  CASE hfi_id
      WHEN 117 THEN 'True'
      ELSE 'False'
  END AS hfi_id_117
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Actually It restricts my way, I can't set case for **hfi_id**, if one more hfi_id added as row, i need to convert that into column dynamically...

Comment: @ShreekumarS: next time explain better; you asked something, provided an example of what you wanted to have and now you're asking more... do it better next time ;)

Comment: @ShreekumarS: I tried it again and it works for me. Check my query again ;)

Comment: @ShreekumarS: I think you're trying with records all having hfi_id=116

Comment: hey dude, thanks for your hint, using your query and MySQL functions it's working as i needed. thank you