# fetch distinct column values in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot, unpivot

This is the data:

```
id    name     period      data1    data2
===================================================
111   name1    monthly     aaaaa    bbbbb
111   name1    quaterly    ccccc    ddddd
111   name1    halfYearly  eeeee    fffff
111   name1    annually    ggggg    hhhhh
```

I want query which fetch data in a single row like

```
id    name     monthlYdata1    monthlYdata2      quaterlydata1    quaterlydata2      halfYearlydata1    halfYearlydata2      annuallydata1    annuallydata2
==========================================================================================================================================================
111   name1    aaaaa           bbbbb             ccccc            ddddd              eeeee              fffff                ggggg            hhhhh
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle version 11 or higher has the PIVOT command which can do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but, this will work in all of them:

```
select id,
  name,
  max(case when period = 'monthly' then data1 end) as MonthlyData1,
  max(case when period = 'monthly' then data2 end) as MonthlyData2,
  max(case when period = 'quaterly' then data1 end) as quarterlyData1,
  max(case when period = 'quaterly' then data2 end) as quarterlyData2,
  max(case when period = 'halfYearly' then data1 end) as halfYearlyData1,
  max(case when period = 'halfYearly' then data2 end) as halfYearlyData2,
  max(case when period = 'annually' then data1 end) as annuallyData1,
  max(case when period = 'annually' then data2 end) as annuallyData2
from yourtable
group by id, name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211ad/1)

If you are using an RDBMS that has a `PIVOT` function, then you can do the following which uses both an `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` to produce the results.  As Andriy M pointed out the `UNPIVOT` is assuming that the datatype for both `data1` and `data2` are the same types, if not, then a conversion would need to take place to `UNPIVOT` the data:

**Oracle 11g:**

```
select *
from
(
  select id, name, value, 
    period||data new_col
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value for data in (data1, data2)
  ) u
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in ('monthlyDATA1', 'monthlyDATA2',
                  'quaterlyDATA1', 'quaterlyDATA2',
                  'halfYearlyDATA1', 'halfYearlyDATA2',
                  'annuallyDATA1', 'annuallyDATA2')
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a8e7/5)

**SQL Server:**

```
select *
from
(
  select id, name, value, 
    period+data new_col
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value for data in (data1, data2)
  ) u
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in ('monthlyDATA1', 'monthlyDATA2',
                  'quaterlyDATA1', 'quaterlyDATA2',
                  'halfYearlyDATA1', 'halfYearlyDATA2',
                  'annuallyDATA1', 'annuallyDATA2')
) p
```

Comment: You should probably stipulate that your UNPIVOT/PIVOT queries are assuming that `data1` and `data2` are of the same type.

Comment: @AndriyM agreed, posted a note.  Thanks

Comment: thanks a tonn..
i had just removed aggregate function max() & it worked successfully :):)

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from the query itself.

**Get the id and name from the query1 and concatenate that query with the monthly, quaterly and annually data using the id fetched from the query1**

Answer (score 0):

**three use full articles for your question:**

[How to Display rows as Columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888631/how-to-display-rows-as-columns-in-mysql)

[How to pivot a MySQL entity-attribute-value schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema)

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,75357,75357#msg-75357

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should retrieve all differents id's into a temporal table..

```
Select DISTINCT id
into #tmpIds
from Table
```

Then create a temporal table with the columns you want (`id`, `name`, `monthlYdata1`, `monthlYdata2`, `quaterlydata1`, `quaterlydata2`, `halfYearlydata1`, `halfYearlydata2`, `annuallydata1`, `annuallydata2`), and loop through your first temporary table in order to get the id's.

For each id you should do:

```
Insert into #tmpTable
   @id,
   '',
  (Select data1 from Table where id=@id and period='monthly') as monthlyData1
  ...
```

This is the first solution that came to my mind.