# What is best performance for Retrieving MySQL EAV results as Relational Table

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I want to extract results from EAV (entity-attribute-value) tables, or more specifically entity-metadata tables (think like wordpress `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) as a "nicely formatted relational table", **in order to do some sorting and/or filtering**.

I've found some examples of how to format the results within the query (as opposed to writing 2 queries and joining the results in code), but I would like to know the "most efficient" method for doing so, especially for larger result sets.

And when I say "most efficient", I mean for something like the following scenarios:

> Get all Entities with last name like XYZ
>
> Return a list of Entities sorted by birthday

---

e.g. turn this:

```
** ENTITY **
-----------------------
ID  | NAME | whatever
-----------------------
 1  | bob  | etc
 2  | jane | etc
 3  | tom  | etc

** META **
------------------------------------
ID | EntityID | KEY         | VALUE
------------------------------------
 1 |   1      | first name  | Bob
 2 |   1      | last name   | Bobson
 3 |   1      | birthday    | 1983-10-10
 . |   2      | first name  | Jane
 . |   2      | last name   | Janesdotter
 . |   2      | birthday    | 1983-08-10
 . |   3      | first name  | Tom
 . |   3      | last name   | Tomson
 . |   3      | birthday    | 1980-08-10
```

into this:

```
** RESULTS **
-----------------------------------------------
EID | NAME | first name | last name    | birthday
-----------------------------------------------
 1  | bob  | Bob        | Bobson       | 1983-10-10
 2  | jane | Jane       | Janesdotter  | 1983-08-10
 3  | tom  | Tom        | Tomson       | 1980-08-10
```

so I can sort or filter by any of the meta fields.

---

I found some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema), but I can't find any discussion of which performs better.

**Options**:

1. **GROUP_CONCAT**:

   ```
   SELECT e.*, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS('||', m.KEY, m.VALUE) ORDER BY m.KEY SEPARATOR ';;' )
   FROM `ENTITY` e JOIN `META` m ON e.ID = m.EntityID
   ```
2. **Multi-Join**:

   ```
   SELECT e.*, m1.VALUE as 'first name', m2.VALUE as 'last name', m3.VALUE as 'birthday'
   FROM `ENTITY` e
   LEFT JOIN `META` m1
       ON e.ID = m1.EntityID AND m1.meta_key = 'first name'
   LEFT JOIN `META` m2
       ON e.ID = m2.EntityID AND m2.meta_key = 'last name'
   LEFT JOIN `META` m3
       ON e.ID = m3.EntityID AND m3.meta_key = 'birthday'
   ```
3. **Coalescing**:

   ```
   SELECT e.*
      , MAX( IF(m.KEY= 'first name', m.VALUE, NULL) ) as 'first name'
      , MAX( IF(m.KEY= 'last name', m.VALUE, NULL) ) as 'last name'
      , MAX( IF(m.KEY= 'birthday', m.VALUE, NULL) ) as 'birthday'
   FROM `ENTITY` e
   JOIN `META` m
       ON e.ID = m.EntityID
   ```
4. **Code**:

   ```
   SELECT e.* FROM `ENTITY` e WHERE e.ID = {whatever};
   ```

   *in PHP, create a placeholder object from result*

   ```
   SELECT m.* FROM `META` m WHERE m.EntityID = {whatever};
   ```

   *in PHP, loop through results and attach to entity object like:*
       *`$e->{$result->key} = $result->VALUE`*

Which is better in general, and for filtering/sorting?

Related questions:

1. [Binding EAV results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721699/binding-eav-results)
2. [How to Pivot a MySQL entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema)

Comment: If there was a bet on performance and only one chance to shoot, I'd go for the multi-join.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY e.ID` in options 1 and 3.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/most-performant-sql-query-needed) on dba.se

Comment: **Option 5.** Correlated subqueries in SELECT list... `SELECT e.id, (SELECT m.val FROM meta m WHERE m.key = 'fi' AND m.e_id = e.id ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 1) AS fi, (SELECT n.val FROM meta n WHERE n.key = 'fo' AND n.e_id = e.id ORDER BY n.id LIMIT 1) AS fo FROM entity e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything using pivot or aggregates will probably be faster, as they don't require the table to be self-joined.  The join based approaches will require the optimiser to perform several sub-query operations and then join the results together.  For a small data set this might not matter so much, but this could significantly degrade performance if you're doing an analytic query on a larger data set,

Comment: based on your link in the question comments, I'm marking this as the answer, although I was hoping for something more definite :)

Comment: i have eav system and its growing how can i port it to another saving module to can save my system ? and the question is which way you prefer to saving (json?)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out would be to test, off course. The answer may be different depending on the size of the dataset, the number of different meta-keys, their distribution (do all entities have values for all meta-keys? or only for a few of them?), the settings of your database server and possibly many other factors.

If I were to guess, I'd say that the cost of the `JOIN` operations in option 2 would be smaller than the cost of `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions needed in options 1 and 3.

So, I would expect to find Option 2 faster than 1 and 3.

To measure Option 4, you'll have to consider more factors as the application may be in another server so the loads of the two (db and application) servers and the number of clients that will be requesting these results have to be taken into account.

---

Sidenote: you need `GROUP BY e.ID` in options 1 and 3.