# Select recent events with all activities listed SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that will store events.  Each event has different activities.  The database is made as so (I know this is not the best database design, but I am working with what was given to me) :

```
eventID | date       | eventname | activity
___________________________________________
0001    | 01/01/2012 | name1     | activty1
0002    | 01/01/2012 | name1     | activty2
0003    | 01/05/2012 | event2    | activty1
0004    | 01/05/2012 | event2    | activty2
0005    | 01/07/2012 | name1     | activty1
```

The same event can have multiple activities.  The only way I can get the all records from an event (activities) is by the eventname column.

What I am trying to do is get the last 20 events with all it's activities.  Therefore I cannot simply select 20 rows (using `LIMIT` as this would not get me 20 events everytime as some events have 2 activities and others 10).

I cannot use `SELECT DISTINCT eventname` because some events have same name, on different dates.  What I would need is to have a distinct eventname only if the date is different.

I'm lost for ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the last 20 events but each eventname can only be represented once?

Comment: @ConradFrix I am looking for 20 events, with all their activities.  I am looking to get basically x number of records that represent 20 events. - hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Could you query the last 20 events, and then loop around them in a cursor, looking up all the activities for each one, then inserting those into a table object, and then returning those rows? Possibly not the fastest way to do it, but it would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Look at the first answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema It appears to use a MySQL command I'm not familiar with, but should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  event
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT   eventName, Date
  FROM     events
  GROUP BY eventName, Date
  ORDER BY Date DESC
  LIMIT    20
)
  AS last_20_events
    ON  last_20_events.eventName = events.eventName
    AND last_20_events.Date      = events.Date
```

Comment: Close, and this makes sense, but my eventIDs are all different.  The eventIDs are different for every entry in the database.  I've edited the questions slightly to display this.

Comment: This here gave me the last 20 records, but it will be more then 20 records, since I want 20 events, not 20 activities.

Comment: just change the eventID references to eventName.

Comment: @blo0p3r - No idea what your last comment meant, but I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the last comment.  Bug with browser : Thanks... this did most of the work... had to figure out a few things, but for the purpose of this question this did help... I only needed to add restrictions for dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT eventName, date, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(activity ORDER BY activity SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM events
GROUP BY eventName, date
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 20
```

I don't have access to a MySQL DB at the moment, so I haven't been able to test this. This answer is based on other accepted answers on SO (search for group_concat)