# MySQL Query Speed Up

Tags: mysql, database, performance, left-join

I'm having a problem with the speed of a query - it's running at about 16 seconds at the moment, and I need to speed it up!

My table scheme is as follows:

Users:

- id (int 10, primary key)
- username (varchar 100)
- password (varchar 100)

Users_meta:

- id (int 10, primary key)
- user (int 10)
- meta (varchar 100)
- value (longtext)

I need to return data from various rows in the user meta table (such as first name, last name etc.) as columns. This query does the job, but runs too slow:

```
SELECT
Users.id as id,
Users.username as username,
firstName.value as metaFirstName,
lastName.value as metaLastName,
userLevel.value as metaUsername,
employer.value as metaEmployer,
gto.value as metaGTO
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN (Users_meta as firstName) ON (firstName.user = Users.id AND firstName.meta = 'first_name')
LEFT JOIN (Users_meta as lastName) ON (lastName.user = Users.id AND lastName.meta = 'last_name')
LEFT JOIN (Users_meta as userLevel) ON (userLevel.user = Users.id AND userLevel.meta = 'user_level')
LEFT JOIN (Users_meta as employer) ON (employer.user = Users.id AND employer.meta = 'employer')
LEFT JOIN (Users_meta as gto) ON (gto.user = Users.id AND gto.meta = 'gto')
```

I also need to be able to add WHERE and ORDER BY clauses to the query.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: What indexes have you defined (use `SHOW INDEXES FROM table1`)?

Comment: From users: PRIMARY - id, and From users_meta: PRIMARY - id

Comment: This question is addressed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema

Comment: I really don't want to use group_concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is faster. But maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Users.id as id,
    Users.username as username,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Users_meta.meta = 'first_name' THEN Users_meta.value ELSE NULL END) AS metaFirstName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Users_meta.meta = 'last_name' THEN Users_meta.value ELSE NULL END) AS metaLastName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Users_meta.meta = 'user_level' THEN Users_meta.value ELSE NULL END) AS metaUsername,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Users_meta.meta = 'employer' THEN Users_meta.value ELSE NULL END) AS metaEmployer,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Users_meta.meta = 'gto' THEN Users_meta.value ELSE NULL END) AS metaGTO
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN Users_meta
        ON Users_meta.user = Users.id
GROUP BY
    Users.ID,
    Users.username
```

Comment: This works great! Only problem is that it won't work if I wanted to add a WHERE clause using the meta data. I guess I should have mentioned I was planning on doing that, too! For example, I can't run "WHERE metaUserLevel = 'student'". I've amended the original description to include this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I would first add a compound index on table meta: `(meta, user, value)`. Or `(user, meta, value)`. These would sure help if you had additional `WHERE` conditions in your query.

The query has now to use (almost) all the data in table `Users_meta` so these indexes may not be used.

The `longtext` datatype is another problem. Are you sure you need so wide column there?

Comment: Thanks guys - this does help a bit :) Still running quite slow though.

Comment: @Curbis: Can you add the `EXPLAIN` plan after this index was added?