# select query that sums rows and returns them as columns

Tags: mysql

Weird question... I know. So let me explain.

Here is a my text table

```
    quota     |    metric_id
     100      |        1
     20       |        2
     100      |        15
     50       |        1
     30       |        2
     20       |        15
     50       |        1
     200      |        2
     10       |        15
```

I want a SELECT statement that would return the following

```
    id_1    |     id_2     |      id_15 
    200     |     250      |      130
```

Here is what the data is:

```
Column `id_1` is sum of the 3 rows where `metric_id=1`
Column `id_2` is sum of the 3 rows where `metric_id=2`
Column `id_15` is sum of the 3 rows where `metric_id=15`
```

Any help?

Comment: Convert `Column 'id_1' is sum of the 3 rows where 'metric_id=1'` into SQL and you're good to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pivot a MySQL entity-attribute-value schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema)

Comment: Is `metric_id` static? Just those 3 values?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT SUM(quota * (metric_id = 1)) AS id_1,
       SUM(quota * (metric_id = 2)) AS id_2,
       SUM(quota * (metric_id = 15)) AS id_15
FROM Table1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bb629/1). It's quite simple: `metric_id = N` is 1 for the rows having that attribute equal to N, and 0 for all the other rows. Multiplying `quota` by 1 is `quota`, by 0 - 0, and the rest is an easy task for `SUM()` function.

Comment: thank you for the help. This is exactly what the doctor ordered

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select SUM(case when metric_id = 1 then quota END) id_1
       SUM(case when metric_id = 2 then quota END) id_2
       SUM(case when metric_id = 15 then quota END) id_15
FROM Table1
```