# Complicated selection in MySQL (EAV table)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table like this:

```
|---group---|---property---|---value---|
|     a     |   prop1      |    yes    |
|     a     |   prop2      |    yes    |
|     a     |   prop3      |    no     |
|     b     |   prop1      |    yes    |
|     b     |   prop2      |    no     |
|     b     |   prop3      |    no     |
|     c     |   prop1      |    no     |
|     c     |   prop2      |    no     |
|     c     |   prop3      |    no     |
```

I need to filter out only those groups that have `yes` near `prop1`.
I could use `having` statement, but this would take any `yes` value. The problem is that I do not have my properties as column names but as rows in a column instead. Soooo... is it even possible to do this?

There should be only groups `a` and `b` in my resulting table...

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: ``SELECT `group` FROM `tablename` WHERE `property` = 'prop1' AND `value` = 'yes'``?

Comment: `where property = 'prop1' and value = 'yes'`? Otherwise do as @jarlh said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sub query to pick first the list of groups that has value `Property` = 'prop1' and `Value` = 'Yes'. Then select all records for those list of Groups as below-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE Group IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT `Group`
    FROM your_table
    WHERE `Property` = 'prop1'
    AND `Value` = 'Yes'
)
```

You can add several different properties as-

```
....
WHERE 
(
    `Property` = 'prop1'
    AND `Value` = 'Yes'
)
AND -- You can also use OR here if you need rows if any of the condition is true
(
    `Property` = 'prop3'
    AND `Value` = 'No'
)
```

Comment: This works, but what if I want to combine several different properties?  For example if I want `prop1` to be `yes` and `prop3` to be `no`?

Comment: you can add more condition in sub query as per requirement.

Comment: added sample code for combining several different properties.

Answer (score 1):

Single propety is straightforward

```
select distinct group 
from myTable
where property = 'prop1' and  value ='yes';
```

Comment: And what about multiple properties?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649802/how-to-pivot-a-mysql-entity-attribute-value-schema

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where `group` = t.`group`
  and (
    (property = 'prop1' and `value` = 'yes')
    or
    (property = 'prop2' and `value` = 'no') 
  )
)
```

You can combine conditions in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you can also write this (although it may have more limited ability to utilise indexes...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE(x,y) IN((1,'yes'),(2,'no'),(3,'maybe'));
```